# Is it possible to do an inplace merge without temporary storage?

Tags: c++, algorithm

I was just thinking, if I were to implement `std::inplace_merge` it would probably look something like this:

```
template <class Bi, class Cmp>
void inplace_merge(Bi first, Bi middle, Bi last, Cmp cmp) {
    if(first != last) {
        typedef typename iterator_traits<Bi>::value_type T;
        typedef typename iterator_traits<Bi>::difference_type Dist;

        const Dist count = distance(first, last);
        if(count != 1) {
            // can I avoid this allocation?
            T *const temp = new T[count];       
            merge(first, middle, middle, last, temp, cmp);      
            copy(temp, temp + count, first);
            delete [] temp;
        }
    }
}
```

I know that I could just use the existing implementation, but that's kind of besides the point. **I was just curious if there was a better algorithm than what I am aware of.**

The reason this came to mind is that most of the c++ standard library (all of the STL if I recall correctly) lets the user specify how and where to perform allocations, but if `std::inplace_merge` requires an allocation by design, it seems that there is no way to control this if it were an issue.

I think a hint at the answer comes from the standard itself regarding the complexity of `std::inplace_merge`:

> Complexity: When enough additional
>   memory is available, (last - first) -
>   1 comparisons. If no additional memory
>   is available, an algorithm with
>   complexity N log N (where N is equal
>   to last -first) may be used.

To me this implies that the known efficient versions of the algorithm require extra storage. Am I reading that right? If so, is there any mention of where the storage is supposed to come from?

Comment: In-place, *by definition*, does not require any extra memory allocations (it just requires O(1) temporary storage on the stack).  Your implementation is not in-place.

Comment: @Adam: incorrect, it means that the results are in the same storage as the source (as opposed to just `merge` which puts the results into a buffer supplied by the caller). For example, STLPort uses temporary space in the form of: `_Temporary_buffer<_BidirectionalIter, _Tp> __buf(__first, __last);` if you look at their implementation.

Comment: After further research, it appears that there is not a single definition of "in-place" (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_algorithm).  The traditional definition used by algorithm theorists is one that uses O(1) extra storage, whereas the one used by the C++ standard is apparently one that uses the same storage for input and output.

Comment: @Adam: fair enough point. Thanks for clarifying that there is more than one way to interpret "in-place"

Comment: I make the same inference as you do.  Perhaps there has been a recent discovery of a O(1)-extra-memory-requiring linear-time merge, but it was unknown to the STL creators who I imagine to be a bunch of very smart people, so I regard it as unlikely.

Comment: More discussion and answers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm . Indeed, the hard part in mergesort is the fast, in-place, stable merge, the rest is straightforward.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There are several known algorithms for merging in-place, though some of them are fairly complex.  The general way in which they work is doing an out-of-place merge, using some of the array elements themselves as the external storage space.  I know that Alex Stepanov and Paul McJones' "Elements of Programming" details one algorithm.

I recently read a paper on in-place merging called ["Practical In-Place Merging"](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.1155&rep=rep1&type=pdf) that details a fairly simple algorithm for doing this sort of merge.  I coded up [an implementation of this algorithm](http://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=inplace-merge) in a way that is close to the interface of `std::inplace_merge`, though there are a few differences.  Perhaps there's something in there that you might find useful?

Comment: Probably one of the most well documented pieces of code I saw. There a few C-isms in there (comments, casts) but it's very well presented.

Comment: +1 This answer is made of pure awesomeness and flat-out win. I'm familiar with the paper mentioned, but taking the time to implement it, even if not for this answer, then proffering it up as an live-action reference is simply stellar. Thank you.