# an even and odd placed sorted array

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

We have an array that is even placed sorted and oddly placed sorted, meaning that the sub-array with even indexes is sorted and the sub-array with odd indexes is sorted.

for example - `{1,4,2,7,4,18,5,19,20}` the two sorted subarray are `{1,2,4,5,20}` and `{4,7,18,19}` - one group with the even indexes and the other with odd indexes.

Is there a way to sort this uniquely sorted array with `O(1)` space complexity and `O(n)` time? (meaning to rearrange it to be normally sorted)

Comment: Some example input would be helpful.

Comment: ... you're only asking for algorithm idea and not the whole code, are you?...

Comment: @user202729 yes

Comment: Given that you already have two sorted sub-arrays then merge sort is the obvious way to go.  You just need to keep careful track of your indexes since the two sub-arrays are interleaved.

Comment: @rossum That uses more than O(1) extra memory.

Comment: Looks like [c++ - Is it possible to do an inplace merge without temporary storage? - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373307/is-it-possible-to-do-an-inplace-merge-without-temporary-storage?noredirect=1&lq=1) . Although I'm not sure what the complexity of the linked paper in the answer is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to do an inplace merge without temporary storage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4373307/is-it-possible-to-do-an-inplace-merge-without-temporary-storage)

Comment: Okay, I checked out the paper, it's O(n)/O(1), definitely satisfied. Flag as duplicate.

Comment: Actually, I forgot that the order is a bit different; still, I think you should be able to use something from that. If you can shuffle them to the "normal" order (should be possible) then just use the algorithm.

Comment: @user202729: `O(n)[time]/O(1)[space]` How do you arrive at/Where did you find O(1) space? I see O(√2) - o(n), but not O(1).

Comment: @greybeard "Wepresent a novel, yet straightfotward
**linear-time algorithm** for merging two sorted lists in a **fixed
amount of additional space**. "

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve this in O(n) time and O(1) space, you're searching for a mergesort, which only uses O(1) space. Just split in odd and even indexes to divide your values in half.

You can read read about why the common implementation of mergesort needs at least O(n) space in this question:
[Merge sort time and space complexity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10342890/merge-sort-time-and-space-complexity)

Thank to user202729 for giving me a second look on that topic.
While your given implementation can reach O(1) space, you dont have a time complexity of O(n log n) anymore, it is O(n²)

But if you repacing the merge part with 2 pointers, climbing both the indexes of the arrays that need to be merged and do a swaping it should be possible to have O(n log n) again

Comment: This is not correct, it claims that that particular implementation of merge sort need O(n) space, not that *there's no algorithm*. (in fact it's *already* possible to implement O(1)-memory merge sort, see link above)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best performance you can get is `O(1) - space` and `O(n log n) - time`. This is **in-place merge sort**.

```java
public final class InPlaceMergeSort {

    public static void sortAsc(int[] arr) {
        sortAsc(arr, 0, arr.length - 1);
    }

    private static void sortAsc(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
        if (hi > lo) {
            int mid = lo + (hi - lo) / 2;
            sortAsc(arr, lo, mid);
            sortAsc(arr, mid + 1, hi);
            merge(arr, lo, mid, hi);
        }
    }

    private static void merge(int[] arr, int lo, int mid, int hi) {
        if (arr[mid] > arr[mid + 1]) {
            for (int i = lo, j = mid, k = mid + 1; i <= j && k <= hi; i++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[k]) {
                    rotateRight(arr, i, k++);
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void rotateRight(int[] arr, int lo, int hi) {
        int tmp = arr[hi];

        if (hi - lo >= 0)
            System.arraycopy(arr, lo, arr, lo + 1, hi - lo);

        arr[lo] = tmp;
    }

}
```

Comment: Nope, this algorithm is even more wrong, a rotate step is course case O(n). See comment https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment11573033_2571114

Comment: Can you provide a test case that brake this algo?