# Mergeing of two arrays without using a 3rd array

Tags: c

What is the C code for mergeing two unsorted arrays without using a 3rd array.
Eg 
array1={1,3,5,7}
array2={2,4,6}
Output should be
array1={1,2,3,4,5,6,7}.

This is the code i have written.But this doesnt work if the number of array elements are same in both arrays.kindly help me in fixing this bug.

```
void merge(int a[],int b[],int ele1,int ele2)
{
int i,j,k,ele3;
ele3=ele1+ele2;
for(i=1,k=0;k<ele2;i=i+2)
{
    j=ele1;
    while(j>=i)
    {
        a[j]=a[j-1];
        j--;
    }
    a[j+1]=b[k];
    k++;ele1++;
}
for(i=0;i<ele3;i++)
printf("%d ",a[i]);
 }

main() 
{ 
int a[]={1,3,5},b[]={2,4},ele1,ele2; 
ele1=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); ele2=sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]); 
merge(a,b,ele1,ele2); 
}
```

Comment: Does any one the first 2 arrays have sufficient space to hold?

Comment: Nothing is mentioned in the question.This was an interview question I got.They said its all ur wish wen I asked if there is memory

Comment: You say unsorted arrays, but the example given is for sorted arrays.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merging two arrays without using extra space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4903585/merging-two-arrays-without-using-extra-space)

Comment: If that is exactly how your interview question is proposed, I'd be more concerned with the facilitation of requirements from your prospective future employer than actually solving the problem. If the **real** problem is performing a merge-sort in-place, [that subject has been widely discussed and solutions proposed for 30+ years](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm). To say the algorithms to accomplish it are non-trivial would be a gross understatement.

Comment: @NikhilP.R Have you written any code for this?

Comment: hey sorry for not responding..i was first time to this blog.so i din knw anything.

Comment: void merge(int a[],int b[],int ele1,int ele2)
{
 int i,j,k,ele3;
 ele3=ele1+ele2;
 for(i=1,k=0;k<ele2;i=i+2)
 {
  j=ele1;
  while(j>=i){
   a[j]=a[j-1];
   j--;
  }
  a[j+1]=b[k];
  k++;ele1++;
 }
 for(i=0;i<ele3;i++)
 printf("%d ",a[i]);
}
main()
{
 int a[]={1,3,5},b[]={2,4},ele1,ele2;
 ele1=sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]);
 ele2=sizeof(b)/sizeof(b[0]);
 merge(a,b,ele1,ele2);
}

Answer (score 1):

It can be done easily if any one of the array is capable of holding all elements, Otherwise it can be done if any one of the array is dynamic array, In case of dynamic array we can change the size of the array by using `realloc` so, after that we merge it easily

The solution will be like [Not tested, Its likely answer]

```
void merge(int ar1[], int ar2[])
{
  int len = ar1.length;
  int totalLength= (ar1.length+ar2.length);
  ar1= (int*)realloc(ar1,(totalLength)*sizeof(int));

  for (int i=len,index=0; i<totalLength; i++)
  {

    ar1[i]=ar2[index];
    index++;

  }
}
```

Comment: @kiran.....dat doesnt work.

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: Did to you tried?

Comment: Aborted..core dumped error...

Comment: By this logic u meant mergeing all the elements of 2nd array at the end of first? Dat is not wat I want.can u please help in doin this..coz tomorrow I have to.answer this question infront of interview panel

Comment: "Dat is not what I want" - then state *exactly*, and *clearly* in your question, the requirements, and your efforts to attain them thus far.

Comment: My requirement is I have 2 arrays one is array1={3,5,1,2} and 2nd array is array2={6,9,7}. Output should be array1={1,2,3,5,6,7,9}.This I have to.accomplish without using a 3rd array.

Comment: @KiranKumar Please stop responding to this blatant code begging with no effort shown by the OP. By answering such questions you only encourage code beggars to post more trash on this site.

Comment: Yeah, I will stop. Thank you.

Comment: hey sorry...i am first time to this blog.i dnt even know how to put my code..whenever i am typing its being printed without any next line.i have developed a code for it..i have put that in a comment above.

Comment: But that doesnt work if number of array elemnts are same in both arrays.kindly help me fix this bug