# Merge Sort in place for python (Cant find what is wrong)

Tags: python, merge, mergesort

I was reading about merge sort(In place) in my algorithm book (Intro to algorithms 3rd edition Cormen), and I decided to implement it in Python. The problem is that I can't find what I am doing wrong... I saw some code in C++, but even with that I can't fix it.

Here is my code:

```
def MERGE(A,start,mid,end):
    L=[0]*(mid - start + 1)
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        L[i] = A[start+i]
    L[len(L) - 1] = 100000 # centinel, (fix)
    R=[0]*(end - mid + 2)
    for j in range(len(R) - 1):
        R[j] = A[mid+j]

    R[len(R) - 1] = 100000
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = start
    for l in range(k,end):
        if(L[i] < R[j]):
            A[l] = L[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            A[k] = R[j]
            j = j + 1   

def mergeSort(A,p,r):
    if p < r:
        mid = int((p+r)/2)
        mergeSort(A,p,mid)
        mergeSort(A,mid+1,r)
        MERGE(A,p,mid,r) 

A  = [20, 30, 15, 21, 42, 45, 31, 0, 9]
mergeSort(A,0,len(A)]
```

When I run the code I have some index problems:

```
File "myrealmerge.py", line 9, in MERGE
R[j] = A[mid+j]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I know that this my be a "dumb question" and that there is some related post, but I tried the suggestions in there and It does not work for me...

Can anyone help me? T
Thanks!

Comment: How is this in place? You're using additional storage for `L` and `R`.

Comment: Upon further inspection, I actually think your problem is in the usage of your `range` function just above the line where you get an `IndexError`. You are aware that `range(len(A))` where A is a list, actually returns a list of *all* valid indices of A? You don't need to do `range(len(R) - 1)`. And as agf noted, this is not in-place.

Comment: Ok, what I mean by "in place" is that i dont want to use a another Array Result to have the information. (Not another copy of A in Other array but with the sorted elements). @ShashankGupta What you mean by that I dont need to do range(len(R) - 1)?? What I can do?

Comment: what is `p` and `r` in function `mergeSort` ? Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This code works fine:

```
def MERGE(A,start,mid,end):
    L = A[start:mid]
    R = A[mid:end]
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = start
    for l in range(k,end):
        if j >= len(R) or (i < len(L) and L[i] < R[j]):
            A[l] = L[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            A[l] = R[j]
            j = j + 1  

def mergeSort(A,p,r):
    if r - p > 1:
        mid = int((p+r)/2)
        mergeSort(A,p,mid)
        mergeSort(A,mid,r)
        MERGE(A,p,mid,r)

A  = [20, 30, 21, 15, 42, 45, 31, 0, 9]
mergeSort(A,0,len(A))
print A
```

I tried to minimize the change from your code.

Good luck!

---

(Added)

You can check the dividing process by using this code.

```
def MERGE(A,start,mid,end):
    # Do nothing
    pass

def mergeSort(A,p,r):
    if r - p > 1:
        mid = int((p+r)/2)
        print A[p:mid],A[mid:r]
        mergeSort(A,p,mid)
        mergeSort(A,mid,r)
        MERGE(A,p,mid,r)

A  = [20, 30, 21, 15, 42, 45, 31, 0, 9]
mergeSort(A,0,len(A))
```

The result is as follows:

```
[20, 30, 21, 15] [42, 45, 31, 0, 9]
[20, 30] [21, 15]
[20] [30]
[21] [15]
[42, 45] [31, 0, 9]
[42] [45]
[31] [0, 9]
[0] [9]
```

This is what we want. However, 'mid+1' makes invalid result. Here is the test code:

```
def MERGE(A,start,mid,end):
    # Do nothing
    pass

def mergeSort(A,p,r):
    if r - p > 1:
        mid = int((p+r)/2)
        print A[p:mid],A[mid+1:r]    # Changed
        mergeSort(A,p,mid)
        mergeSort(A,mid+1,r)         # Changed
        MERGE(A,p,mid,r)

A  = [20, 30, 21, 15, 42, 45, 31, 0, 9]
mergeSort(A,0,len(A))
```

result:

```
[20, 30, 21, 15] [45, 31, 0, 9]
[20, 30] [15]
[20] []
[45, 31] [9]
[45] []
```

---

(Added)

Here is a code using 'mid+1':

```
# New indexing function that includes the right index.
def get_partial_list(origin_list, left_index, right_index): # Added
    return origin_list[left_index:right_index+1]


def MERGE(A,start,mid,end):
    L = get_partial_list(A,start,mid)
    R = get_partial_list(A,mid+1,end)
    i = 0
    j = 0
    k = start
    for l in range(k,end+1):            # changed
        if j >= len(R) or (i < len(L) and L[i] < R[j]):
            A[l] = L[i]
            i = i + 1
        else:
            A[l] = R[j]
            j = j + 1  

def mergeSort(A,p,r):
    if r - p > 0:                          # changed
        mid = int((p+r)/2)
        mergeSort(A,p,mid)
        mergeSort(A,mid+1,r)             # changed
        MERGE(A,p,mid,r)

A  = [20, 30, 21, 15, 42, 45, 31, 0, 9]
mergeSort(A,0,len(A)-1)                 # changed
print A
```

I've added new indexing function. Is this the code you expected?

Comment: Thanks!! I have a doubt with the indices: why in mergeSort you dont pass mid+1 in the second recursive call (it does not work if I pass the + 1)?? Also, did you know ehre I can find some article explaining iterative merge sort?? I have never seen that! (if the code is in python, better for me)

Comment: @Edwardo: I added explanation about 'mid+1'.

Comment: @Edwardo: I'm sorry but I don't know where the code is. However, I think you can implement the iterative version from the recursive version. (reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration)

Comment: Many Many thnaks, the problem is that I (because of my algorithm book) uses mid+1 and len(A) (it begins in zero).But as a C++ programmer, adn the implementation I have seen, they use mid+1 and len(A)-1. I am triyng to change the code in that way, but I dont know how to do it exactly... I understand that the slice copy ( [:] ) is inclusive (left index) and exclusive (right index). But even that (and using your debug method) cant achieve it... Can you help me? (I am a bit ashamed right now :/ )

Comment: @Edwardo: I think that the indexing('mid', 'mid+1') is not important. The important thing is concept of the algorithm. Because of the python's indexing policy(exclude right index), I used 'mid'.
You can make a python code that using 'mid+1', but you should make your own indexing function(to include the right index). Do not get stuck with the pseudo code. Follow the concept!

Comment: @Edwardo: I've added a code that using 'mid+1'. Do I understand your intention correctly?

Comment: Yes! thank you! but, Although this looks great, the first one (without mid+1) looks more natural for a python programmer right? I mean which one you prefer?

Comment: @Edwardo: Yes, the first one is more natural for python programmers. I also prefer the first one. Good luck!

Comment: A[start:mid] is a copy, so this is unfortunately not in place.

Comment: Space complexity change for Merge sort and In-place Merge sort. the above is not in place merge sort. [sample](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/in-place-merge-sort/).

Comment: What does "p" mean in `mergesort(A, p, r)`

Answer (score 1):

The solutions provided by lancif and krishna Prasad dont not have space complexity O(1).

Here is algorithm  in place merge sorting for Py3 with space complexity O(1).
The main function `sort_imerge` uses 2 auxiliary functions `wmerge` and `wsort`.

This solution based on C code that discussed on:
[other SO topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm/15657134#15657134) and on [good C implementation](https://github.com/liuxinyu95/AlgoXY/blob/algoxy/sorting/merge-sort/src/mergesort.c)
Also you can find full Python code with doctests  [here](https://github.com/Orangefish/algo/blob/master/sorting_and_search/sort_merge.py)

```
def sort_imerge(Seq, l=0, u=None):
    """ Merge sorting, mutable input. 
    Input sequence changed in place. 

    Time: O(n * log n)
        log n -- levels
        n -- elements on each level must be merged

    Space (additional): O(1) 
        input changed in place

    Returns None

    """
    u = len(Seq) if u is None else u
    if  u - l > 1:
        m = l + (u - l) // 2
        w = l + u - m  
        wsort(Seq, l, m, w)
        while w - l > 2:
            n = w
            w = l + (n - l + 1) // 2
            wsort(Seq, w, n, l)
            wmerge(Seq, l, l + n - w, n, u, w)
        n = w
        while n > l: # fallback to insert sort
            for m in range(n, u):
                if Seq[m-1] > Seq[m]:
                    Seq[m-1], Seq[m] = Seq[m], Seq[m-1]
            n -= 1

def wmerge(Seq, i, m, j, n, w):
    """Merge subarrays [i, m) and [j, n) into work area w.
    All indexes point into Seq.
    The space after w must be enough to fit both subarrays.
    """
    while i < m and j < n:
        if Seq[i] < Seq[j]:
            Seq[i], Seq[w] = Seq[w], Seq[i]
            i += 1
        else:
            Seq[j], Seq[w] = Seq[w], Seq[j]
            j += 1
        w += 1
    while i < m:
        Seq[i], Seq[w] = Seq[w], Seq[i]
        i += 1
        w += 1
    while j < n:
        Seq[j], Seq[w] = Seq[w], Seq[j]
        j += 1
        w += 1

def wsort(Seq, l, u, w):
    """Sort subarray [l, u) and put reuslt into work area w.
    All indexes point into Seq.
    """
    if  u - l > 1:
        m = l + (u - l) // 2
        sort_imerge(Seq, l, m)
        sort_imerge(Seq, m, u)
        wmerge(Seq, l, m, m, u, w)
    else:
        while l < u:
            Seq[l], Seq[w] = Seq[w], Seq[l]
            l +=1
            w +=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursively split the array into left and right part and then merge it as per your requirements i.e `ASC` or `DESC`, Check the below code:

```
def merge_sort(a):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return a

    left = [];
    right = [];

    mid = len(a)/2

    left = a[0:mid]
    right = a[mid:(len(a))]

    print left
    print right
    #exit()

    left = merge_sort(left)
    right = merge_sort(right)

    return merge(left, right)

def merge(left, right):
    result = []
    while len(left) > 0 and len(right) > 0:
        lv = left[0]
        rv = right[0]
        if lv <= rv:
            result.append(lv)
            left.pop(0)
        else:
            result.append(rv)
            right.pop(0)
    while len(left) > 0:
        result.append(left.pop(0))

    while len(right) > 0:
        result.append(right.pop(0))

    return result

A  = [20, 30, 21, 15, 42, 45, 31, 0, 9]

print A
print merge_sort(A)
```

For **understanding** I have printed the intermediate partitioned array have a look into the output:

```
[20, 30, 21, 15, 42, 45, 31, 0, 9]
[20, 30, 21, 15]
[42, 45, 31, 0, 9]
[20, 30]
[21, 15]
[20]
[30]
[21]
[15]
[42, 45]
[31, 0, 9]
[42]
[45]
[31]
[0, 9]
[0]
[9]
[0, 9, 15, 20, 21, 30, 31, 42, 45]
```

Hope this will help you to understand the logic.

Comment: This implementation was easy to understand from others, in C it was so easy to merge sort, but in python it was more than frustrating.

Comment: @mSatyam Thanks.

Comment: Space complexity is still O(n), it's not an in-place Merge sort. [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm)