# MergeSort. Implementation with Iterators

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, sorting

I need to implement the algorithm of mergesort with following interface:

```
template <typename T, typename Comp>
void mergesort(T begin, T end, Comp comp);
```

where *begin* and *end* - iterators for elements of some container of type T, comp - is function of comparing elements, which are stored in container. And

```
template <typename T, typename Comp>
void merge(T beginLeft, T endLeft, T beginRight, T endRight,
                T beginResult, Comp comp);
```

is function of merging of two sorted containers (*beginLeft* and *endLeft* - iterators of the first container,  *beginRight* and *endRight* - of the second) and result should be iterator to the begining of new merged container *beginResult*.

It should be look like [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/merge/).

I've wrote recursive function for merge sort, which calls the procedure of merging.

```
template <typename T, typename Comp>
void mergesort(T begin, T end, Comp comp)
{
    if (begin == std::prev(end))
    {
        return;
    }    

    T middle = begin + std::distance(begin, end) / 2;

    mergesort<T, Comp>(begin, middle, comp);
    mergesort<T, Comp>(middle, end, comp);

    merge<T, Comp>(begin, middle, middle, end, begin, comp);
}

template <typename T, typename Comp>
void merge(T beginLeft, T endLeft, T beginRight, T endRight,
                T beginResult, Comp comp)
{
    while (beginLeft != endLeft && beginRight != endRight)
    {
        if (comp(*beginLeft, *beginRight))
        {
            *beginResult = *beginLeft;
            ++beginResult;
            ++beginLeft;
        }
        else
        {
            *beginResult = *beginRight;
            ++beginResult;
            ++beginRight;
        }
    }

    while (beginLeft != endLeft)
    {
        *beginResult = *beginLeft;
        ++beginResult;
        ++beginLeft;
    } 
    while (beginRight != endRight)
    {
        *beginResult = *beginRight;
        ++beginResult;
        ++beginRight;
    } 
}
```

Function *merge* works correctly, but I don't quite understand, how *mergesort* should work. What argument should I pass to

```
merge<T, Comp>(begin, middle, middle, end, /?...?/, comp);
```

If I pass just *begin* there, than the result of sorting is not correct. Or should I pass there some temporary container. But how can I create it, if I have only type of iterator and don't know the type of elements?

I will be grateful for your help. Thank you!

--ADDED---

Example of merging:

```
vector<int> vec1;
vector<int> vec2;
vector<int> vec3(6);
vec1.push_back(1);
vec1.push_back(3);
vec1.push_back(5);
vec2.push_back(2);
vec2.push_back(4);
vec2.push_back(6);
merge(vec1.begin(), vec1.end(), vec2.begin(), vec2.end(), vec3.begin(), std::less<int>()); 

for (int i = 0; i < vec3.size(); ++i)
{
    std::cout << vec3[i] << std::endl;
}
```

Output is: 1 2 3 4 5 6

Comment: how dyou know that *merge* works correctly if you don't even know how to call it?

Comment: What you require is an in-place merge sort. This is not easy to implement as this link states:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm

Answer (score 2):

For sure you can't use `begin` to store the result. You are still reading from `begin` and merging, so by writing to it you would be overwriting data that are possibly still not read.

You would need temporary memory to write the result to, and then copy back over the original. The memory could be of any type, so long as you can get an iterator over it. Say a `std::vector`.

There's a fundamental problem though. You have the type of all five iterators in `merge` as `T`, but at least the type of `beginResult` should be of a possibly different iterator. Otherwise, you can't know, as you have observed, what temporary container to use.

As you have linked yourself, the template of `std::merge` has different iterator types for the `left`, `right` and `result` iterators.

---

Note: to allocate temporary memory, you need to know the type of elements that `T` is an iterator of. This is simply done by `T::value_type`. See [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator).

Comment: Didn't, even nearly, address the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
template<class BiDirIt, class Compare = std::less<typename std::iterator_traits<BiDirIt>::value_type>>
void merge_sort(BiDirIt first, BiDirIt last, Compare cmp = Compare())
{
        auto const N = std::distance(first, last);
        if (N < 2) return;
        auto middle = first + N / 2;
        merge_sort(first, middle, cmp);
        merge_sort(middle, last, cmp);
        std::inplace_merge(first, middle, last, cmp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your vector as such:

```
std::vector<std::iterator_traits<T>::value_type> result;
```

in a helper function, then call your sort routine:

```
merge_sort(first, last, result.begin());
```

Then once your function comes back with results, you can copy the results to the vector denoted by the user-provided iterators.