# How to use a stack of pointers to arrays, and access two arrays in the same command?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, stack

Just to be clear, this is for a homework assignment. I'm not asking for anyone to do it for me, I'm just stuck on a small portion of it.

I'm asked to implement mergesort, but each new array I make has to be placed in a stack of pointers. In the code below, I'm trying to split up an array recursively, then merge them together. My stack is named ptrs. The merge() function takes two sorted arrays and their sizes.

```
template <typename T>
T* MergeSort<T>::mergeSort(T arr[], int size) {

    int size1 = (int)size/2;
    int size2 = size - size1;

    //I'll have a base case to cover the arrays of size 1 or 2

    ptrs.push(new T[size1]);
    for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++) {
        ptrs.top()[i] = arr[i];
    }

    ptrs.push(new T[size2]);
    for(int i = 0; i < size2; i++) {
        ptrs.top()[i] = arr[i + size1];
    }

    return merge(mergeSort(TODO, size1), mergeSort(ptrs.top(), size2), size1, size2);
```

My problem is marked by my TODO. How can I access the first array, if the second one is now on the top of the stack?

Comment: what is the type of `ptrs`?

Comment: ptrs is a stack of arrays of type T. In my tests, I've been using doubles. And the stack comes from std::stack.

Comment: stack is a poor choice of container here, may I suggest deque? With a deque, push becomes push_back, pop becomes pop_back, top becomes back, and second last element can be accessed with ptrs[ptrs.size()-2]

Comment: Hm. That sounds like it could work. Unfortunately, the assignment is restricted to using a stack. Perhaps my code above is just using the wrong approach?

Comment: I just saw this comment, after writing my answer. But using a stack doesn't make sense to me. The stack's interface is designed to allow  viewing or popping the top element only. You can only view the second if pop the first. But then you start realizing that you don't need a stack, only the two items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you need a stack at all? Since you allocate two new arrays and copy the two portions of the input array, you can recurse on them directly:

```
T* left = new T[size1];
for(int i = 0; i < size1; i++) //...

T* right = new T[size2];
for(int i = 0; i < size2; i++) /...

T* left_sorted  = mergeSort(left,  size1);
T* right_sorted = mergeSort(right, size2);
```

Then merge, being careful to deallocate:

```
delete[] left;
delete[] right;

T* merged = merge(left_sorted, right_sorted, size1, size2);

delete[] left_sorted;
delete[] right_sorted;

return merged;
```

If this is allowed by the assignment, I would strongly recommend using `std::vector` instead of plain arrays + sizes. You could also consider [in-place merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm) to avoid all those allocations.

Comment: Though your way is not how I was allowed to do it, thanks for a working answer. It led me to my solution, which was to make array pointers and use them normally, but make sure to push anything I "new"ed before leaving the method. Then I let the destructor take care of my stack.

Comment: @user3448821 I trust your instructor has good reason for this :-)