# Merge sort using one array

Tags: java, mergesort, array-algorithms

My merge sort algorithm is given below...

As we know this algorithm needs extra memory. Is there any way to do sorting with only one array? (Sorting in a single array.)

My merge sort algorithm is:

```
//LeftPos = start of left half;
//RightPos = start of right half
void  Merge(int A[ ], int LeftPos, int RightPos, int RightEnd) 
{
    int LeftEnd = RightPos – 1;
    int TmpPos = 1
    int NumElements = RightEnd – LeftPos + 1;
    int TempArray[NumElements];
    while(leftPos <= LeftEnd && RightPos <= RightEnd)
        if(A[LeftPos] <= A[RightPos])
            TmpArray[TmpPos++] = A[LeftPos++];
        else
            TmpArray[TmpPos++] = A[RightPos++];
    while(LeftPos <= LeftEnd)   //Copy rest of first half   
        TmpArray[TmpPos++] = A[LeftPos++];
    while(RightPos <= RightEnd) //Copy rest of second half      TmpArray[TmpPos++] = A[RightPos++];
    for(int i = 1; i <= NumElements; i++) //Copy TmpArray back
        A[LeftPos++] = TmpArray[i];
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort in-place using the merge sort algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm)

Answer (score 0):

Check these links:

[How to sort in-place using the merge sort algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm)

Java code which will fit your question:

https://github.com/bakeraj4/In-Place-Merge-Sort/blob/master/mergeMain.java

The technique you are looking for is "in place", for future searches you can use it to find better results in the internet.