# HeapSort vs MergeSort space complexity

Tags: sorting, mergesort, heapsort, space-complexity

I was brushing up on my algorithms when I read the following line in the CLRS book:

> Like insertion sort, but unlike merge sort, heap sort sorts in place: only a constant number of array elements are stored outside the input array at any time.

Does this refer to the left & right sublists that merge sort uses for the divide & conquer?

If yes, can we somehow enhance over the merge sort algorithm to skip creating those sublists?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort in-place using the merge sort algorithm?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge sort indeed needs some working space:

- In naive implementations, each recursive call allocates 2 subarrays to copy the left and right parts as their elements may be overwritten during the merge phase. This working space amounts to the size of the dataset for the last merge phase.
- In more advanced implementations, a single working array is allocated in an initial phase and is passed to the recursive calls, or used in the iteration for non recursive implementations. Depending on the implementation details, the size of this working array can be reduced to half the size of the dataset plus 1, or the next power of 2 for bottom-up iterative implementations.
- If the data elements are large, such as structures with multiple fields, there is an alternative approach to require less working space: allocate an array of pointers to the dataset, sort this array and use the resulting array to shuffle the original dataset in place. This may require less space but the shuffle phase is tricky.

All of the above require some working space proportional to **N**, hence a space complexity of **O(N)**, which is much worse than insertion sort, heap sort, shell sort and quick sort.

Note that merge sort applied to lists does not require **O(N)** space, but rather **O(log N)** space, either for recursive calls in top-down implementations or in an array of pointers to sublists for iterative bottom-up implementations. However extra **O(N)** space is already present in the data structures to store the `next` pointers.

Answer (score 1):

By "constant number of array elements are stored outside the input array", it means the tree being built during the process of making heap. It is constant number because the time complexity of diving the data into root, left heap and right heap is O(1).