# why is the standard merge sort not in place?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In the merge algorithm of merge sort, I don't understand we have to use auxiliary arrays L, R? Why can't we just keep 2 pointers corresponding which element we're comparing in the 2 subarrays L and R so that the merge-sort algorithm remains inplace?

Thanks.

Comment: What is the *standard* merge sort, and where is it defined?

Comment: Try it and find out.

Comment: Your question does not make much sense if you don't explicitly refer to the implementation/definition of the merge sort you're looking at.

Comment: It is not easy to do in-place mergesort. This question may be relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm

Answer (score 7):

say you split your array s.th. L uses the first half of the original array, and R uses the second half.

then say that durign merge the first few elements from R are smaller than the smallest in L. If you want to put them in the correct place for the merge result, you will have to overwrite elements from L that have not been processed during the merge step yet.

of course you can make a diferent split. But you can always construct such an (then slightly different) example.

Answer (score 1):

If you ever tried to write a merge sort in place, you will soon find out why you can't wen you are merging the 2 sub arraies - you basically need to read from and write to the same range of the array, and it will overwrite each other. Hence we need any auxiliary array:

```
vector<int> merge_sort(vector<int>& vs, int l, int r, vector<int>& temp)
{
  if(l==r) return vs; // recursion must have an end condition

  int m = (l+r)/2;
  merge_sort(vs, l, m, temp);
  merge_sort(vs, m+1, r, temp);

  int il = l, ir=m+1, i=l;
  while(il <= m && ir <= r)
  {
    if(vs[il] <= vs[ir])
      temp[i++] = vs[il++];
    else
      temp[i++] = vs[ir++];
  }

  // copy left over items(only one of below will apply
  while(il <= m) temp[i++] = vs[il++];
  while(ir <= r) temp[i++] = vs[ir++];

  for(i=l; i<=r; ++i) vs[i] = temp[i];

  return vs;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My first post here.  Be gentle!

Here's my solution for a simple and easy-to-understand stable in-place merge-sort.  I wrote this yesterday.  I'm not sure it hasn't been done before, but I've not seen it about, so maybe?

The one drawback to the following in-place merge algorithm can degenerate into O(n²) under certain conditions, but is typically O(n.log₂n) in practice.  This degeneracy can be mitigated with certain changes, but I wanted to keep the base algorithm pure in the code sample so it can be easily understood.

Coupled with the O(log₂n) time complexity for the driving merge_sort() function, this presents us with a typical time complexity of O(n.(log₂n)²) overall, and O(n².log₂n) worst case, which is not fantastic, but again with some tweaks, it can be made to almost always run in O(n.(log₂n)²) time, and with its good CPU cache locality it is decent even for n values up to 1M, but it is always going to be slower than quicksort.

```
//                     Stable Merge In Place Sort
//
//
// The following code is written to illustrate the base algorithm. A good
// number of optimizations can be applied to boost its overall speed
// For all its simplicity, it does still perform somewhat decently.
// Average case time complexity appears to be: O(n.(log₂n)²)

#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define swap(x, y)    (t=(x), (x)=(y), (y)=t)

// Both sorted sub-arrays must be adjacent in 'a'
// Assumes that both 'an' and 'bn' are always non-zero
// 'an' is the length of the first sorted section in 'a', referred to as A
// 'bn' is the length of the second sorted section in 'a', referred to as B
static void
merge_inplace(int A[], size_t an, size_t bn)
{
    int t, *B = &A[an];
    size_t  pa, pb;     // Swap partition pointers within A and B

    // Find the portion to swap.  We're looking for how much from the
    // start of B can swap with the end of A, such that every element
    // in A is less than or equal to any element in B.  This is quite
    // simple when both sub-arrays come at us pre-sorted
    for(pa = an, pb = 0; pa>0 && pb<bn && B[pb] < A[pa-1]; pa--, pb++);

    // Now swap last part of A with first part of B according to the
    // indicies we found
    for (size_t index=pa; index < an; index++)
        swap(A[index], B[index-pa]);

    // Now merge the two sub-array pairings.  We need to check that either array
    // didn't wholly swap out the other and cause the remaining portion to be zero
    if (pa>0 && (an-pa)>0)
        merge_inplace(A, pa, an-pa);

    if (pb>0 && (bn-pb)>0)
        merge_inplace(B, pb, bn-pb);
} // merge_inplace

// Implements a recursive merge-sort algorithm with an optional
// insertion sort for when the splits get too small.  'n' must
// ALWAYS be 2 or more.  It enforces this when calling itself
static void
merge_sort(int a[], size_t n)
{
    size_t  m = n/2;

    // Sort first and second halves only if the target 'n' will be > 1
    if (m > 1)
        merge_sort(a, m);

    if ((n-m)>1)
        merge_sort(a+m, n-m);

    // Now merge the two sorted sub-arrays together. We know that since
    // n > 1, then both m and n-m MUST be non-zero, and so we will never
    // violate the condition of not passing in zero length sub-arrays
    merge_inplace(a, m, n-m);
} // merge_sort

// Print an array */
static void
print_array(int a[], size_t size)
{
    if (size > 0) {
        printf("%d", a[0]);
        for (size_t i = 1; i < size; i++)
            printf(" %d", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
} // print_array
 
// Test driver
int
main()
{
    int a[] = { 17, 3, 16, 5, 14, 8, 10, 7, 15, 1, 13, 4, 9, 12, 11, 6, 2 };
    size_t  n = sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]);
 
    merge_sort(a, n);
 
    print_array(a, n);

    return 0;
} // main
```