# c++ merging more sorted subarray into one array

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

How I can merge effectively more sorted subarray to one array. (So as haven't to create new array with same size.)

I have got array:

```
int LENGHT = 12;
int ARRAY[LENGHT] = {5,8,6,3,48,65,1,8,9,20,21,57};
```

For example bubble sort in fourth thread:

```
int ARRAY[LENGHT] = {5,8,6,3,48,65,1,8,9,20,57,21};
thread_1 -> BubbleSort(0, LENGTH/4, ARRAY);
thread_2 -> BubbleSort(LENGTH/4, LENGTH/2, ARRAY);
thread_3 -> BubbleSort(LENGTH/2, (3*LENGTH)/4, ARRAY);
thread_4 -> BubbleSort((3*LENGTH)/4, LENGTH, ARRAY);
```

I get:

```
ARRAY[] = {3,5,6,  1,8,8,  9,45,65,  20,21,57};
```

What is the best way to merging to one array?

```
{3,5,6,  1,8,8,  9,45,65,  20,21,57} -> {1,3,5,  6,8,8,  9,20,21,  45,57,65}
```

Comment: The best strategy in the overwhelming majority of cases is to create a new array. There are [ways around it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2571049/335858), but they hardly are worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `std::inplace_merge`, like this(c++11):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

template <typename T, size_t N>
char (&ArraySizeHelper(T (&array)[N]))[N];

#define ARRAY_LEN(arr) (sizeof(ArraySizeHelper(arr)))

int main()
{
    int ARRAY[] = {3,5,6,  1,8,8,  9,45,65,  20,21,57};
    const size_t SORTED_CHUNK_SIZE = 3;
    for (size_t i = SORTED_CHUNK_SIZE; i < ARRAY_LEN(ARRAY); i += SORTED_CHUNK_SIZE) {
        auto beg = std::begin(ARRAY);
        auto mid = beg + i;
        auto end = mid + SORTED_CHUNK_SIZE;
        std::inplace_merge(beg, mid, end);
    }
    std::copy(std::begin(ARRAY),
          std::end(ARRAY),
          std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout,",")
        );
    std::cout << "\n";

}
```

**update**

if you use threads, you can use such strategy:
let's say you have 4 threads, 4 threads sort 4 chunks of array,
then 2 of these 4 threads with `std::inplace_merge` merge 4 chunks into 2 chunks,
and then 1 of these 4 threads merge this two chunks into 1.

Also look at here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/parallelism/existing#inplace_merge

and implentation  https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/master/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/parallel/quicksort.h

Answer (score 0):

If you must sort an array the absolute fastest utilising all possible hardware threads then you need to create a quicksort that can utilize multiple threads.

A lot of the Standard Template Library all work to perform a couple of functions, Quicksort being one of them.  When you call `std::sort` it's quite possible that you are calling something that looks like:

```
template <class ForwardIt>
void sort(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last)
{
    if (first == last) return;
    auto pivot = *std::next(first, std::distance(first,last)/2);
    ForwardIt middle1 = std::partition(first, last, 
                         [&pivot](const auto& em){ return em < pivot; });
    ForwardIt middle2 = std::partition(middle1, last, 
                         [&pivot](const auto& em){ return !(pivot < em); });
    sort(first, middle1);
    sort(middle2, last);
 }
```

(credit to en.cppreference)

The main function here is `std::partition`. If you divide the partitioned range into blocks of equal size based on the number of threads you will end up with partially sorted range - all the elements that return true to the predicate will be before those that returned false.  It also crucially returns an iterator to that element - helpfully called `middle` in the above example.

By storing these returned iterators in an array you can then

```
for (auto i=n-2; i>0; --i) 
{ 
    auto begin = r[i]; 
    auto mid = std::next(first, b * (i + 1)); 
    auto end = last; 
    swap_block<Iter>()(begin, mid, last); 
} 
swap_block<Iter>()(r[0], std::next(first, b), last);
```

where `swap_block` looks like:

```
template<typename Iter> 
struct swap_block 
{ 
    void operator()(Iter first, Iter mid, Iter last) 
    {
        std::rotate(first, mid, last); 
    }    
};
```

Using `std::rotate` is very inefficient for large blocks/those where `mid` is towards the end of the range.  In those cases it would be better to use `std::reverse` (and remember kids if you want a stable `swap_block` you would need 3 `std::reverse`s!)

TL;DR: Learn to use the STL algorithm library effectively.

There is a version of parallel_partition that I have written [here](https://github.com/grahamreeds/parallel_partition/blob/master/parallel_partition.cpp).