# Merge two sorted arrays with O(1) extra space

Tags: arrays, algorithm, merge, time-complexity

We get `O(m+n)` on merging 2 sorted arrays if we are allowed to use `O(n)` extra space of temporary array. So all elements are merged into one temporary array.

But, how to perform merging if I am only allowed to use `O(1)` extra space?

Comment: You don't need hash table for sorted arrays merging, and space is needed only for resulting array.

Comment: Where should the merged contents, i.e. m+n elements, be kept?

Comment: They can be kept in any array

Comment: you nd to be more specific with memory allocated. are you given two arrays or just one array with m+n entries. your O notation is all for time complexity?

Comment: I have edited. see now

Comment: In-place merge algorithms exist, but simple ones reveal significantly worse behavior, others are too complex to implement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm

Comment: What has your research discovered? Have you not come up with *any* possible approaches? Please note the tooltips when you hover over the up and down vote arrows next to your question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to merge two sorted arrays with O(1) extra space.

We can achieve this by using **Insertion sort.**

But the time complexity to merge two sorted arrays using O(1) extra space would be **O(n^2).**

If We allowed to use O(n) extra space, then we can use **Merge sort** with time complexity of just **O(nlogn).**

Comment: what's O(n2)? is it O(n^2)?