# Block merge sort converted from C to Java not sorting correctly; is my refactoring of pointers to blame?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, merge

EDIT: This has been fixed! I missed some referenced variables that I accounted for here: https://github.com/MusicTheorist/JavaGrailSort

I'm trying to convert Andrey Astrelin's implementation of Block merge sort, nicknamed "Grailsort", from C to Java, however, my version is not sorting arrays of ints in the proper order.

So far, I have taken out the SORT_TYPE struct, separated the pointer from the array being sorted, and have converted some incompatible boolean conditionals.

Here is Mr. Astrelin's code:
https://github.com/Mrrl/GrailSort/blob/master/GrailSort.h

Here is the majority of my code:

```
private static int grail_BinSearchLeft(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int len,int key){
    int a=-1,b=len,c;
    while(a<b-1){
        c=a+((b-a)>>1);
        if(SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+c],arr[key])>=0) b=c;
        else a=c;
    }
    return b;
}
private static int grail_BinSearchRight(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int len,int key){
    int a=-1,b=len,c;
    while(a<b-1){
        c=a+((b-a)>>1);
        if(SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+c],arr[key])>0) b=c;
        else a=c;
    }
    return b;
}

// cost: 2*len+nk^2/2
private static int grail_FindKeys(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int len,int nkeys){
    int h=1,h0=0;  // first key is always here
    int u=1,r;
    while(u<len && h<nkeys){
        r=grail_BinSearchLeft(arr,arrPtr+h0,h,arrPtr+u);
        if(r==h || SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+u],arr[arrPtr+(h0+r)])!=0){
            grail_rotate(arr,arrPtr+h0,h,u-(h0+h));
            h0=u-h;
            grail_rotate(arr,arrPtr+(h0+r),h-r,1);
            h++;
        }
        u++;
    }
    grail_rotate(arr,arrPtr,h0,h);
    return h;
}

// cost: min(L1,L2)^2+max(L1,L2)
private static void grail_MergeWithoutBuffer(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int len1,int len2){
    int h;
    if(len1<len2){
        while(len1!=0){
            h=grail_BinSearchLeft(arr,arrPtr+len1,len2,arrPtr);
            if(h!=0){
                grail_rotate(arr,arrPtr,len1,h);
                arrPtr+=h;
                len2-=h;
            }
            if(len2==0) break;
            do{
                arrPtr++; len1--;
            } while(len1!=0 && SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr],arr[arrPtr+len1])<=0);
        }
    } else{
        while(len2!=0){
            h=grail_BinSearchRight(arr,arrPtr,len1,arrPtr+(len1+len2-1));
            if(h!=len1){
                grail_rotate(arr,arrPtr+h,len1-h,len2);
                len1=h;
            }
            if(len1==0) break;
            do{
                len2--;
            } while(len2!=0 && SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+len1-1],arr[arrPtr+len1+len2-1])<=0);
        }
    }
}

// arr[M..-1] - buffer, arr[0,L1-1]++arr[L1,L1+L2-1] -> arr[M,M+L1+L2-1]
private static void grail_MergeLeft(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int L1,int L2,int M){
    int p0=0;
    int p1=L1;
    L2+=L1;

    while(p1<L2){
        if(p0==L1 || SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+p0],arr[arrPtr+p1])>0){
            grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(M++),arrPtr+(p1++));
        } else{
            grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(M++),arrPtr+(p0++));
        }
    }
    if(M!=p0) grail_swapN(arr,arrPtr+M,arrPtr+p0,L1-p0);
}
private static void grail_MergeRight(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int L1,int L2,int M){
    int p0=L1+L2+M-1;
    int p2=L1+L2-1;
    int p1=L1-1;

    while(p1>=0){
        if(p2<L1 || SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+p1],arr[arrPtr+p2])>0){
            grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(p0--),arrPtr+(p1--));
        } else{
            grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(p0--),arrPtr+(p2--));
        }
    }
    if(p2!=p0) while(p2>=L1) grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(p0--),arrPtr+(p2--));
}

private static void grail_SmartMergeWithBuffer(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int alen1,int atype,int len2,int lkeys){
    int p0=-lkeys,p1=0,p2=alen1,q1=p2,q2=p2+len2;
    int ftype=1-atype;  // 1 if inverted
    while(p1<q1 && p2<q2){
        if(SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+p1],arr[arrPtr+p2])-ftype<0) grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(p0++),arrPtr+(p1++));
        else grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(p0++),arrPtr+(p2++));
    }
    if(p1<q1){
        alen1=q1-p1;
        while(p1<q1) grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(--q1),arrPtr+(--q2));
    } else{
        alen1=q2-p2;
        atype=ftype;
    }
}
private static void grail_SmartMergeWithoutBuffer(int[]arr,int arrPtr,int alen1,int atype,int _len2){
    int len1,len2,ftype,h;

    if(_len2 == 0) return;
    len1=alen1;
    len2=_len2;
    ftype=1-atype;
    if(len1 != 0 && SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+(len1-1)],arr[arrPtr+len1])-ftype>=0){
        while(len1!=0){
            if (ftype!=0)
                h = grail_BinSearchLeft(arr,arrPtr+len1,len2,arrPtr);
            else
                h = grail_BinSearchRight(arr,arrPtr+len1,len2,arrPtr);
            if(h!=0){
                grail_rotate(arr,arrPtr,len1,h);
                arrPtr+=h;
                len2-=h;
            }
            if(len2==0){
                alen1=len1;
                return;
            }
            do{
                arrPtr++; len1--;
            } while(len1!=0 && SORT_CMP(arrPtr,arrPtr+len1)-ftype<0);
        }
    }
    alen1=len2; atype=ftype;
}

// build blocks of length K
// input: [-K,-1] elements are buffer
// output: first K elements are buffer, blocks 2*K and last subblock sorted
static void grail_BuildBlocks(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int L,int K,int[] extbuf,int bufPtr,int LExtBuf){
    int m,u,h,p0,p1,rest,restk,p,kbuf;
    kbuf=K<LExtBuf ? K : LExtBuf;
    while((kbuf&(kbuf-1)) != 0) kbuf&=kbuf-1;  // max power or 2 - just in case

    if(kbuf != 0){
        System.arraycopy(arr, arrPtr-kbuf, extbuf, bufPtr, kbuf);
        for(m=1;m<L;m+=2){
            u=0;
            if(SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+(m-1)],arr[arrPtr+m])>0) u=1;
            grailSet(arr,arrPtr+m-3,arrPtr+m-1+u);
            grailSet(arr,arrPtr+m-2,arrPtr+m-u);
        }
        if(L%2!=0) grailSet(arr,arrPtr+L-3,arrPtr+L-1);
        arrPtr-=2;
        for(h=2;h<kbuf;h*=2){
            p0=0;
            p1=L-2*h;
            while(p0<=p1){
                grail_MergeLeftWithXBuf(arr,arrPtr+p0,h,h,-h);
                p0+=2*h;
            }
            rest=L-p0;
            if(rest>h){
                grail_MergeLeftWithXBuf(arr,arrPtr+p0,h,rest-h,-h);
            } else {
                for(;p0<L;p0++) arr[p0-h]=arr[p0];
            }
            arrPtr-=h;
        }
        System.arraycopy(arr, arrPtr+L, extbuf, bufPtr, kbuf);
    } else{
        for(m=1;m<L;m+=2){
            u=0;
            if(SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+(m-1)],arr[arrPtr+m])>0) u=1;
            grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(m-3),arrPtr+(m-1+u));
            grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(m-2),arrPtr+(m-u));
        }
        if(L%2!=0) grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(L-1),arrPtr+(L-3));
        arrPtr-=2;
        h=2;
    }
    for(;h<K;h*=2){
        p0=0;
        p1=L-2*h;
        while(p0<=p1) {
            grail_MergeLeft(arr,arrPtr+p0,h,h,-h);
            p0+=2*h;
        }
        rest=L-p0;
        if(rest>h){
            grail_MergeLeft(arr,arrPtr+p0,h,rest-h,-h);
        } else{
            grail_rotate(arr,arrPtr+p0-h,h,rest);
        }
        arrPtr-=h;
    }
    restk=L%(2*K);
    p=L-restk;
    if(restk<=K) grail_rotate(arr,arrPtr+p,restk,K);
    else grail_MergeRight(arr,arrPtr+p,K,restk-K,K);
    while(p>0){
        p-=2*K;
        grail_MergeRight(arr,arrPtr+p,K,K,K);
    }
}

// arr - starting array. arr[-lblock..-1] - buffer (if havebuf).
// lblock - length of regular blocks. First nblocks are stable sorted by 1st elements and key-coded
// keys - arrays of keys, in same order as blocks. key<midkey means stream A
// nblock2 are regular blocks from stream A. llast is length of last (irregular) block from stream B, that should go before nblock2 blocks.
// llast=0 requires nblock2=0 (no irregular blocks). llast>0, nblock2=0 is possible.
private static void grail_MergeBuffersLeft(int[] arr,int keysPtr,int midkey,int arrPtr,int nblock,int lblock,boolean havebuf,int nblock2,int llast){
    int l,prest,lrest,frest,pidx,cidx,fnext;

    if(nblock==0){
        l=nblock2*lblock;
        if(havebuf) grail_MergeLeft(arr,arrPtr,l,llast,-lblock);
        else grail_MergeWithoutBuffer(arr,arrPtr,l,llast);
        return;
    }

    lrest=lblock;
    frest=SORT_CMP(arr[keysPtr],arr[midkey])<0 ? 0 : 1;
    pidx=lblock;
    for(cidx=1;cidx<nblock;cidx++,pidx+=lblock){
        prest=pidx-lrest;
        fnext=SORT_CMP(arr[keysPtr+cidx],arr[midkey])<0 ? 0 : 1;
        if(fnext==frest){
            if(havebuf) grail_swapN(arr,arrPtr+prest-lblock,arrPtr+prest,lrest);
            prest=pidx;
            lrest=lblock;
        } else{
            if(havebuf){
                grail_SmartMergeWithBuffer(arr,arrPtr+prest,lrest,frest,lblock,lblock);
            } else{
                grail_SmartMergeWithoutBuffer(arr,arrPtr+prest,lrest,frest,lblock);
            }

        }
    }
    prest=pidx-lrest;
    if(llast!=0){
        if(frest!=0){
            if(havebuf) grail_swapN(arr,arrPtr+prest-lblock,arrPtr+prest,lrest);
            prest=pidx;
            lrest=lblock*nblock2;
            frest=0;
        } else{
            lrest+=lblock*nblock2;
        }
        if(havebuf) grail_MergeLeft(arr,arrPtr+prest,lrest,llast,-lblock);
        else grail_MergeWithoutBuffer(arr,arrPtr+prest,lrest,llast);
    } else{
        if(havebuf) grail_swapN(arr,arrPtr+prest,arrPtr+(prest-lblock),lrest);
    }
}

private static void grail_LazyStableSort(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int L){
    int m,h,p0,p1,rest;
    for(m=1;m<L;m+=2){
        if(SORT_CMP(arr[arrPtr+m-1],arr[arrPtr+m])>0) grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+(m-1),arrPtr+m);
    }
    for(h=2;h<L;h*=2){
        p0=0;
        p1=L-2*h;
        while(p0<=p1){
            grail_MergeWithoutBuffer(arr,arrPtr+p0,h,h);
            p0+=2*h;
        }
        rest=L-p0;
        if(rest>h) grail_MergeWithoutBuffer(arr,arrPtr+p0,h,rest-h);
    }
}

// keys are on the left of arr. Blocks of length LL combined. We'll combine them in pairs
// LL and nkeys are powers of 2. (2*LL/lblock) keys are guarantied
private static void grail_CombineBlocks(int[] arr,int keysPtr,int arrPtr,int len,int LL,int lblock,boolean havebuf,int[] xbuf, int bufPtr){
    int M,b,NBlk,midkey,lrest,u,p,v,kc,nbl2,llast;
    int arr1;

    M=len/(2*LL);
    lrest=len%(2*LL);
    if(lrest<=LL){
        len-=lrest;
        lrest=0;
    }
    if(xbuf!=null) System.arraycopy(arr, arrPtr-lblock, xbuf, bufPtr, lblock);
    for(b=0;b<=M;b++){
        if(b==M && lrest==0) break;
        arr1=arrPtr+b*2*LL;
        NBlk=(b==M ? lrest : 2*LL)/lblock;
        grail_SortIns(arr,keysPtr,NBlk+(b==M ? 1 : 0));
        midkey=LL/lblock;
        for(u=1;u<NBlk;u++){
            p=u-1;
            for(v=u;v<NBlk;v++){
                kc=SORT_CMP(arr[arr1+p*lblock],arr[arr1+v*lblock]);
                if(kc>0 || (kc==0 && SORT_CMP(arr[keysPtr+p],arr[keysPtr+v])>0)) p=v;
            }
            if(p!=u-1){
                grail_swapN(arr,arr1+(u-1)*lblock,arr1+p*lblock,lblock);
                grail_swap1(arr,keysPtr+(u-1),keysPtr+p);
                if(midkey==u-1 || midkey==p) midkey^=(u-1)^p;
            }
        }
        nbl2=llast=0;
        if(b==M) llast=lrest%lblock;
        if(llast!=0){
            while(nbl2<NBlk && SORT_CMP(arr1+NBlk*lblock,arr1+(NBlk-nbl2-1)*lblock)<0) nbl2++;
        }
        if(xbuf!=null) grail_MergeBuffersLeftWithXBuf(arr,keysPtr,keysPtr+midkey,arr1,NBlk-nbl2,lblock,nbl2,llast);
        else grail_MergeBuffersLeft(arr,keysPtr,keysPtr+midkey,arr1,NBlk-nbl2,lblock,havebuf,nbl2,llast);
    }
    if(xbuf!=null){
        for(p=len;--p>=0;) grailSet(arr,arrPtr+p,arrPtr+p-lblock);
        System.arraycopy(xbuf, bufPtr, arr, arrPtr-lblock, lblock);
    }else if(havebuf) while(--len>=0) grail_swap1(arr,arrPtr+len,arrPtr+len-lblock);
}

private static void grail_commonSort(int[] arr,int arrPtr,int Len,int[]extbuf,int bufPtr,int LExtBuf){
    int lblock,nkeys,findkeys,ptr,cbuf,lb,nk;
    boolean havebuf,chavebuf;
    int s;

    if(Len<16){
        grail_SortIns(arr,arrPtr,Len);
        return;
    }

    lblock=1;
    while(lblock*lblock<Len) lblock*=2;
    nkeys=(Len-1)/lblock+1;
    findkeys=grail_FindKeys(arr,arrPtr,Len,nkeys+lblock);
    havebuf=true;
    if(findkeys<nkeys+lblock){
        if(findkeys<4){
            grail_LazyStableSort(arr,arrPtr,Len);
            return;
        }
        nkeys=lblock;
        while(nkeys>findkeys) nkeys/=2;
        havebuf=false;
        lblock=0;
    }
    ptr=lblock+nkeys;
    cbuf=havebuf ? lblock : nkeys;
    if(havebuf) {
        grail_BuildBlocks(arr,arrPtr+ptr,Len-ptr,cbuf,extbuf,bufPtr,LExtBuf);
    }
    else{
        grail_BuildBlocks(arr,arrPtr+ptr,Len-ptr,cbuf,null,bufPtr,0);
    }

    // 2*cbuf are built
    while(Len-ptr>(cbuf*=2)){
        lb=lblock;
        chavebuf=havebuf;
        if(!havebuf){
            if(nkeys>4 && nkeys/8*nkeys>=cbuf){
                lb=nkeys/2;
                chavebuf=true;
            } else{
                nk=1;
                s=cbuf*findkeys/2;
                while(nk<nkeys && s!=0){
                    nk*=2; s/=8;
                }
                lb=(2*cbuf)/nk;
            }
        }
        grail_CombineBlocks(arr,arrPtr,arrPtr+ptr,Len-ptr,cbuf,lb,chavebuf,chavebuf && lb<=LExtBuf ? extbuf : null,bufPtr);
    }
    grail_SortIns(arr,arrPtr,ptr);
    grail_MergeWithoutBuffer(arr,arrPtr,ptr,Len-ptr);
}
```

Blocks of the array are sorted properly until being merged to the left. The array is supposed to be in sorted ascending order.

Thank you so much for reading!!

Comment: I confirmed that the C code is working. Does the failure happen regardless if the external buffer is used or not?  On my system, the external buffer option is slower.

Comment: @rcgldr Happens regardless.

Comment: @rcgldr Check it out whenever you can! https://youtu.be/qlvBsYyGIDo?t=370

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm wondering about line 138:

```
            } while(len1!=0 && SORT_CMP(arrPtr,arrPtr+len1)-ftype<0);
```

Other calls to SORT_CMP are of the form arr[arrPtr], this one on line 138 is passing the indexes instead of the values.

Same issue with line 371:

```
            while(nbl2<NBlk && SORT_CMP(arr1+NBlk*lblock,arr1+(NBlk-nbl2-1)*lblock)<0) nbl2++;
```

Since the entire code with a main testing function is not included, I can't test this.

Comment: Thank you for the help! It seems like this helped, but numbers are still way out of order. Here is the entire code: https://github.com/MusicTheorist/JavaGrailSort/blob/master/GrailSort.java

Comment: Oops, my fault. https://github.com/MusicTheorist/JavaGrailSort/blob/master/GrailSort.java. And to answer your question, it's just a recreational project with a program that visualizes sorting algorithms. Just curious to see if I can get this sort working!

Comment: While I'm looking at this, perhaps you could change the sort to sort floating point values (or strings), which should catch any error related to trying to use a non-integer as an index.

Comment: Nice idea! Thank you so much for your help. Code updated on github.

Comment: @John - just wanted to confirm, the code is fixed now, and the first link in your edited question is the working code?