# Merge N segments of a vector in place C++

Tags: c++, array-merge

I have a `int64_t` vector containing N elements that are divided to k ordered segments.
e.g if N = 9 and K=3 it can look something like that:

```
5,6,7,1,2,3,7,8,9
```

Is there a way to merge the segments in place without first iteratively coping them to another N/K sized arrays and merge?

Comment: What have you tried? Do you have a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt to show us? What happens when you build or run your attempt? What do you expect to happen?

Comment: What do you mean by "merge the segments"?

Comment: ^^ this and how would you do it **with** first iteratatively copying them to another N/K sized arrays?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort in-place using the merge sort algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm)

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about merge-sorting the segments, then you have [std::inplace_merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge). Just do it K-1 times with an increasing number of elements in the first range.