# Is there any process to reduce the space complexity of merge sort?

Tags: mergesort

The merge() function of thr merge sort. The one which merges the sorted sub-arrays into a single sorted array requires foo much memory. Is there any way to reduce the memory needed?

Comment: Maybe related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm

Comment: Based on a 1992 paper, here is a link to [github source](https://github.com/Mrrl/GrailSort) for a merge sort that can run without a buffer. This  particular variation looks for 2 sqrt(n) unique values that can be moved to provide space for merging, and yet maintain stability (since these values are unique, reordering them before sorting doesn't affect stability).