# JavaScript: mergeSort returns RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, algorithm, sorting, recursion, mergesort

I'm currently trying to implement mergeSort in Javascript. I get the following error:

> Users/stevenaguilar/Desktop/algorithms/merge/merge-sort.js:36
>             sort(a, lo, hi) {
>                 ^
>           RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>               at Merge.sort (/Users/stevenaguilar/Desktop/algorithms/merge/merge-sort.js:36:7)

The input is not that big is an element with 16 elements in it.

```
a = ["M", "E", "R", "G", "E", "S", "O", "R", "T", "E", "X", "A","M", "P", "L", "E"]
```

I was able to create the merge sort with Ruby and was able to sort the array. Not sure why I'm getting the above error with JavaScript since im running `Node  v14.0.0`  here is the implementation of the merge sort:

```
class Merge {
  constructor() {
    this.aux = []
  }

  sortPublic(a) {
    this.sort(a, 0, a.length - 1);
  }

  merge(a, lo, mid, hi) {
    let i = lo
    let j = hi
    var mid = mid + 1

    for(let k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
     this.aux[k] = a[k]
    }

    for(let k = lo; k <= hi; k++) {
      if(i > mid) {
        a[k] = this.aux[j++]
      }
      else if(j > hi) {
        a[k] = this.aux[i++]
      }
      else if(this.aux[j] < this.aux[i]) {
        a[k] = this.aux[j++]
      }
      else {
        a[k] = this.aux[i++]
      }
    }

  }

  sort(a, lo, hi) {
    if(lo >= hi) { return; }
    var mid = lo + (lo + hi) / 2
    this.sort(a, lo, mid)
    this.sort(a, mid + 1, hi)
    this.merge(a, lo, mid, hi)
  }
}


let mergeSort = new Merge;
console.log(mergeSort)
let a = ["M", "E", "R", "G", "E", "S", "O", "R", "T", "E", "X", "A", "M", "P", "L", "E"]

mergeSort.sortPublic(a);
```

What is the problem here?

Comment: You reached the stack limit. Your recursion goes too deep.

Comment: He is asking not what the issue is, but where the issue is. @MickaelB.

Comment: Have you tried debugging the problem by logging out the various index values? Clearly your code is incorrectly recursing with bad index values somewhere.

Comment: Make your life easier: start stepping through your code _manually_: take a pen and some paper, and start writing down what the code does at each line (not what it _should_ do, what it _does_). Take an input that is only two elements long and you'll spot the problem really quickly. And as an upside, as an "annoying exercise", you're going to be remembering what you did wrong much better than if you ask people to find it for, because "you" discovered something important, instead of just reading about it.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans thanks for the input so this is a code error? if thats the case I'll follow your advise. It is just hard for me trying to figure out why is the code since merge implementation work by itself when I run it. But good point.

Comment: mid = lo + (lo + hi) / 2. You need to use Math.floor when you calculate (lo+hi)/2, otherwise it's not an integer. So when you pass your mid to next recursion, your hi will always larger than lo. Probably you can use (lo+hi)>>1

Comment: also you may consider use ~~((hi-lo)/2) + lo, ~~ means Math.floor, and use hi-lo can avoid overflow

Comment: @Colin Always remember to mention the caveat when advocating bitwise operations: `~` changes the internal number type from a float, capable of representing integers up to 2^53-1, to strict signed 32 bits. While that is unlikely to be a problem here it's an _incredibly_ important detail. It's also why `~~` isn't special, and in fact wastes some cycles: *any* bitwise noop does this, so `...|0`, `...>>0`, etc all force-floor the number into a signed 32 bit integer, with `|0` usually being the force-floor of choice since it's the least operations _and_ the least number of symbols.

Comment: @Steven it's definitely a code error.one usually associated with people coming to JS from Java, but I suppose Ruby has the same problem: JS maths is real maths, not integer maths. And because arrays are just objects with some indexing logic added on top, accessing `myarray[3.1415]` is the exact same as trying to access any other object property that doesn't exist: you'll get `undefined` back, not "an error" (because there is no error, arrays don't have bounds in JS, they're just key/value pair objects).

Comment: nor is maths involving `undefined` an error: you're just going to get NaN as result. And the same goes for _using_ NaN in maths expressions. JS has some _very_ different rules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`var mid = lo + (lo + hi) / 2` has multiple issues. If you're trying to prevent overflow, `lo + hi` is problematic (the correct formula is `lo + (hi - lo) / 2`). Adding `lo` back in counts it twice. `/ 2` potentially gives a float result which will break the recursive logic and fail as an index.

In terms of design, I don't think there's reason to make merge sort a stateful class and create an instance just to sort an array. This is unnecessary overhead, makes the calling code verbose and potentially introduces bugs. Making the methods `static` makes more sense, assuming you need a class (even this is probably overkill).

`this.aux` persisting between multiple method calls and invocations is ripe for bugs and feels like premature optimization; making it purely local to the `sort` method improves readability, encapsulation and ensures no stale data survives between calls. Yes, creating an array for every frame of `merge` is expensive, but if there's a need to optimize, the merge array can be added to a closure or passed as a parameter. Or the merging can be done [in place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm). Then again, [`Array#sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) is the better choice if performance is your goal.

I also find that running all of the splits using traditional array length protocol where `lo` to `mid` is inclusive of `lo` and exclusive of `mid` and a second chunk inclusive of `mid` and exclusive of `hi` more intuitive. This avoids `mid + 1` and `hi - 1` and looping with `<=` which I find harder to reason about.

```js
class MergeSorter {
  static merge(a, lo, mid, hi) {
    const sorted = [];
    let i = lo;
    let j = mid;
    
    while (i < mid && j < hi) {
      if (a[i] < a[j]) {
        sorted.push(a[i++]); 
      }
      else {
        sorted.push(a[j++]); 
      }
    }
    
    while (i < mid) sorted.push(a[i++]);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < sorted.length; i++) {
      a[lo++] = sorted[i];
    }
  }

  static sort(a, lo=0, hi=a.length) {
    if (lo < hi - 1) {
      const mid = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
      MergeSorter.sort(a, lo, mid);
      MergeSorter.sort(a, mid, hi);
      MergeSorter.merge(a, lo, mid, hi);
    }
  }
}

const a = [..."MERGESORTEXAMPLE"];
MergeSorter.sort(a);
console.log(a.join(""));

const rnd = n => ~~(Math.random() * n);
let passes = 0;
const tests = 10000;

for (let i = 0; i < tests; i++) {
  const a = Array(rnd(25)).fill().map(() => rnd(25));
  const b = a.slice();
  MergeSorter.sort(a);
  b.sort((a, b) => a - b);

  if ("" + a === "" + b) {
    passes++;
  }
}

console.log(`${passes}/${tests} tests passed`);
```

Comment: I'm coming from Java and Ruby so your feedback does show some changes needed in the code, highly appreciated :) . I want to mention in your implementation `const sorted = [];` will be created each time `merge` is call. Therefore there would be an increase in memory space n times merge is call, right? I'm trying to avoid having to create an array inside merge and just have an in place  array that is only created once. However, I do understand your point on `this.aux`

Comment: can you add some context onto why `(hi - lo) / 2` wouldn't work for `mid` and why we need to add lo back `lo + (hi - lo) / 2` I'm struggling trying to understand why we need to add lo back to get to the mid point. I know for some iteration `lo` will start from `mid +1` thanks for your explanation.

Comment: The problem with putting `sorted`on the stack like I did is that it'll hit performance, not memory. It's a tradeoff between readability/safety and allocation expense. If you want to avoid the array allocation you can scope `sorted` out or find an in-place algorithm, but I'd still keep the methods static. If you really care about performance, use the builtin `Array#sort`. So, yes, given that this is a correct implementation, you could look for ways to optimize it, but it seems like you've wound up worrying prematurely about performance at the cost of correctness and readability.

Comment: `(hi - lo) / 2` doesn't work because the correct formula is `(hi + lo) / 2`. The reason you use the subtraction version is because you don't want to overflow an integer (not as big of a problem in JS). We add `lo` back in because we subtracted it from `hi` earlier.

Comment: No problem. If you want an in-place merge sort algorithm, check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm).