# How can I fix the merge sort algorithm in Java and return sorted array from function

Tags: java, sorting, mergesort

I have a problem with implementing a merge sort algorithm in Java: I've done merge sort algorithm but it couldn't produce the right result. I also return the sorted list from the function. How can I also do it?

Here is my merge sort algorithm defined below.

mergeSort method:

```
public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<Person> personList, Comparator<Person> compTr) {
    ArrayList<Person> helper = new ArrayList<Person>();
    mergeSort(personList, helper, 0, personList.size() - 1, compTr);
}
```

mergeSort function:

```
private static void mergeSort(ArrayList<Person> list, 
                              ArrayList<Person> helper, 
                              int low, 
                              int high, 
                              Comparator<Person> compTr) {
    if (low < high) {
        int middle = (low + high) / 2;
        mergeSort(list, helper, low, middle, compTr); //sort left half
        mergeSort(list, helper, middle + 1, high, compTr); //sort right half
        merge(list, helper, low, middle, high, compTr); // merge
    }
}
```

merge algorithm:

```
private static void merge(ArrayList<Person> list, 
                          ArrayList<Person> helper, 
                          int low, 
                          int middle, 
                          int high,
                          Comparator<Person> compTr) {
    //This loop throws Exception
    for (int i = low; i < high + 1; i++) {
        helper.add(i, list.get(i));
    }

    int helperLeft = low;
    int helperRight = middle + 1;
    int current = low;

    while (helperLeft < middle && helperRight < high) {
        if (isGreaterThan(helper.get(helperLeft), helper.get(helperRight), compTr)) {
            list.set(current, helper.get(helperLeft));
            helperLeft++;
        } else {
            list.set(current, helper.get(helperRight));
            helperRight++;
        }
        current++;
    }

    //Copy remaining elements
    int remaining = middle - helperLeft;
    for (int j = 0; j <= remaining; j++) {
        list.set(current + j, helper.get(helperLeft + j));
    }

    // RETURN LIST(list) _-> TO DO 
}
```

Implement Comparator feature

```
public static boolean isGreaterThan(Person helperLeft, Person helperRight, Comparator<Person> compTr) {
    return greaterThan(compTr, helperLeft, helperRight);
}

private static boolean greaterThan(Comparator comp, Person x, Person y) {
    return comp.compare(x, y) > 0;
}
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer

I changed the code

```
 while(helperLeft < middle && helperRight < high) {
```

to

```
 while(helperLeft <= middle && helperRight <= high) {
```

Comment: You answered your own question and accepted it but there are other problems in your code as explained in the other answers.

Comment: @chqrlie What kind of other issue are there in my code block. Can you tell me about it?

Comment: as I explained in my answer, `helper.add(i, list.get(i));` keeps **inserting** extra elements into the `helper` `ArrayList`. This is very inefficient: it requires **O(n*log(n))** extra space instead of just **O(n)** and has a time complexity of **O(n*n*log(n))** which is worse than insertion sort.

Comment: @chqrlie When I use your code block, it throws an error . `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`

Comment: Sorry, there was a bug in the allocation of `helper`: it must be initialized with `ArrayList<Person> helper = new ArrayList<Person>(personList);`

Comment: @chqrlie Thank to your code block, there is less time consuming by using `O(n)`, isn't it.

Answer (score 1):

> I couldn't get a return value as a list from merge function

If I understand you correctly, you are looking for a way to return your sorted list. But in your implementation, you are trying to sort the original list.
That means that you already have a variable pointing to the resulting, sorted list when you call the merge funtion: the variable you use as parameter when calling

```
public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<Person> personList, Comparator<Person> compTr)
```

For example, if you have your persons in an ArrayList called "list", you are sorting this "list".

```
    ArrayList<Person> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        list.add(new Person());
    }
    System.out.println(list);
    mergeSort(list, Comparator.<Person>naturalOrder());
    System.out.println(list);
```

For more information, what you are using is called a inout parameter - as in you give the function your input and receive its output over this parameter.

---

As pointed out in the comments there also are other problems with the code. I suspect one error is here (<= instead of <)

```
(helperRight <= high)
```

and another to be that you used a temp list in an inplace merge sort.

Here a working example can be found:
[How to sort in-place using the merge sort algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm)

Comment: I checked my sort algorithm there is a problem here. İt cannot be implemented sort part correctly. Where is the problem?

Comment: Well, that would probably be worth a new question. I'll look into it

Comment: Ok. I wait your response.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to *return the sorted array*: the array is sorted in place.

Note however these problems:

- the helper array should be allocated with an initial size equal to the size of the array to be sorted. This avoids the problem with `helper.add(i, list.get(i));` that keeps **inserting** extra elements in the middle of the helper array. This is very inefficient: it requires **O(n*log(n))** extra space instead of just **O(n)** and has a time complexity of **O(n*n*log(n))** which is worse than that of insertion sort.

  You would allocate the helper array with

  ```
    ArrayList<Person> helper = new ArrayList<Person>(personList);
  ```

  and you would save the array elements with `helper.set(i, list.get(i))`.
- the `for` loop in `merge` should iterate up to and including the upper bounds:

  ```
    while (helperLeft <= middle && helperRight <= high)
  ```

The convention of including the upper bound is confusing and error prone, it is much simpler to exclude the upper bounds as it removes the need for `-1` / `+1` adjustments.

Here is a modified version:

```java
public static void mergeSort(ArrayList<Person> personList, Comparator<Person> compTr) {
    ArrayList<Person> helper = new ArrayList<Person>(personList);
    mergeSort(personList, helper, 0, personList.size(), compTr);
}

private static void mergeSort(ArrayList<Person> list, 
                              ArrayList<Person> helper, 
                              int low, 
                              int high, 
                              Comparator<Person> compTr) {
    if (high - low >= 2) {
        int middle = low + (high - low) / 2;
        mergeSort(list, helper, low, middle, compTr); //sort left half
        mergeSort(list, helper, middle, high, compTr); //sort right half
        merge(list, helper, low, middle, high, compTr); // merge
    }
}

private static void merge(ArrayList<Person> list, 
                          ArrayList<Person> helper, 
                          int low, 
                          int middle, 
                          int high,
                          Comparator<Person> compTr) {

    for (int i = low; i < high; i++) {
        helper.set(i, list.get(i));
    }

    int helperLeft = low;
    int helperRight = middle;
    int current = low;

    while (helperLeft < middle && helperRight < high) {
        if (isGreaterThan(helper.get(helperLeft), helper.get(helperRight), compTr)) {
            list.set(current, helper.get(helperLeft));
            helperLeft++;
        } else {
            list.set(current, helper.get(helperRight));
            helperRight++;
        }
        current++;
    }

    // Copy remaining elements
    while (helperLeft < middle) {
        list.set(current, helper.get(helperLeft));
        helperLeft++;
        current++;
    }
}
```