# What is wrong with this merge sort algorithm?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, c++11, mergesort

Can someone please tell what is wrong with this piece of code? This code is to sort a set of elements in an array using merge sort.

```
#include<iostream>

void merge(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right){
    int left_ptr = left;
    int right_ptr = mid + 1;
    int size = right - left + 1;       
    int temp[size];
    int k = left;

    while (left_ptr <= mid && right_ptr <= right)
    {
        if(arr[left_ptr] <= arr[right_ptr]){
            temp[k] = arr[left_ptr];
            left_ptr++;
            k++;
        }
        else{
            temp[k] = arr[right_ptr];
            right_ptr++;
            k++;
        }
        
    }

    while (left_ptr <= mid)
    {
        temp[k] = arr[left_ptr];
        left_ptr++;
        k++;
    }

    while (right_ptr <= right)
    {
        temp[k] = arr[right_ptr];
        right_ptr++;
        k++;
    }
    
    for (int i = left_ptr; i < k; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = temp[i];
    }
    
}

void mergeSort(int arr[], int left, int right){
    int mid;
    if (left < right)
    {
        mid = (right + left)/2;
        mergeSort(arr, left, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right);
        merge(arr, left, mid, right);
    }
    
}
int main(){
    int arr[] = {45,8,9,7,4,58,2,34,2,58}; 
    std::cout << arr << std::endl; 
    int size = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(int);
    mergeSort(arr, 0, size - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        std::cout << arr[i] << "    ";
    }

    std::cout << std::endl;
    
}
```

I double checked it with many online codes and I see no error... What do you think went wrong? I tried to implement this using an array in-place (something like quick-sort).

Comment: It's not "in-place" if you use an additional array for merging and then copy it back.

Comment: Use small and systematic test cases instead of large and arbitrary ones. For instance, `{1,0}` gives the output "1 1", and `{2,1,0}` gives "2 2 2". Those are small enough that you can trace through your code by hand and see where you go wrong.

Comment: As a side note, the conventional half-open intervals are conventional because they're easier to program with and much harder to get off-by-one errors with. It's a good idea to become familiar with them, because they are all you will see when you encounter the standard library and other non-beginner code.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to sort in-place using the merge sort algorithm?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a list of things wrong with your code.  I'm taking "wrong" broadly here.  For each bit of code, my primary criticism is style based not "correctness", where the style aimed for is one that makes correctness easier to spot.

Along the way, one of the style criticisms results in spotting what looks like a bug.

```
void merge(int arr[], int left, int mid, int right){
```

1. You are using `int` to refer to offsets in an array.
2. You are using `int[]` parameters, which is a legacy C syntax for `int* arr`.  Use something like `std::span` instead.

Going on:

```
 int left_ptr = left;
```

If your goal is to preserve the original arguments and work on copies, make the original arguments `const` so someone doesn't have to prove they aren't mutated in the body of the function.

```
int right_ptr = mid + 1;
```

You have variables called `_ptr` that aren't pointers.

```
int size = right - left + 1;
```

you appear to not be using half-open intervals.  Use and learn to use half-open intervals.  They are conventional in C++ and they really do get rid of lots of fence-post correcting code.

```
int temp[size];
```

This is not compliant C++.  Practically, even on compilers that support this, many C++ implementations have much smaller stacks than the memory of arrays you might want to sort.  This then results in your code blowing its stack.

Correctness is more important than performance.  Creating dynamically sized objects on the stack leads to programs that engage in undefined behavior or crash on otherwise reasonable inputs.

```
int k = left;
```

this variable does not describe what it does.

```
while (left_ptr <= mid && right_ptr <= right)
while (left_ptr <= mid)
while (right_ptr <= right)
```

there is a lot of code duplication in these loops.

DRY - don't repeat yourself.  Here, if there is a bug in any one of the repeats, if you DRY the bug would be in all uses and easier to spot.  There are a lot of ways to DRY here (lambdas, helper functions, slightly more complex branching and one loop); use one of them.

```
for (int i = left_ptr; i < k; i++)
{
    arr[i] = temp[i];
}
```

looks like a manual std copy?  Also looks like it has a bug, because of course manually reimplementing std copy means you did it wrong.

```
void mergeSort(int arr[], int left, int right){
```

again, legacy C-style array passing.

```
    int mid;
```

No need to declare this without initializing it.  Move declarations as close as possible to their point of first use, and have them fall out of scope as soon as possible.

```
    if (left < right)
    {
        mid = (right + left)/2;
```

make this `int mid =`.

```
        mergeSort(arr, left, mid);
        mergeSort(arr, mid + 1, right);
```

An example of how closed intervals make you have to do annoying fenceposting.

```
        merge(arr, left, mid, right);

mergeSort(arr, 0, size - 1);
```

another fencepost +/- 1 here.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possible errors in the code:

Declaring `int temp[size];` in `merge` is not valid, as `size` is not a constant. You will need to allocate the array dynamically.

Secondly, in the last segment of the `merge` function (the `for` loop), you initialize `i = left_ptr`. However, `left_ptr` is set equal to `mid` before that. I believe you actually want to initialize `i = left`.

EDIT: Just noticed: `temp` does not necessarily have to start at the beginning of `arr`. What I mean is, that each element of `temp` is mapped to a specific element of `arr`, but your code assumes at several plases, that `temp[0]` is mapped to `arr[0]`, which is not true (`temp[0]` is actually mapped to `arr[right]`). There are two ways to fix that.

You can fix the pieces that are based on this assumption. Instead of `arr[i] = temp[i]`, use `arr[i + right] = temp[i]` in the final `for` loop, and initialize `k` as zero.

Second option is to, instead of creating and deleting `temp` in *every single* call to `merge`, create it to be equal in size to `arr` and hold onto it for the entirety of execution of the algorithm (that could be done by creating it outside the algorithm and passing it to each call to `merge` or `MergeSort`) That way, the equal offset assumption would actually be correct.