# time and space complexity of libstdc++ std::inplace_merge (__merge_without_buffer)

Tags: merge, mergesort, in-place

What is the time and space complexity of the algorithm implemented by *__merge_without_buffer* called by libstdc++ *std::inplace_merge*? More specifically, I'm interested in these:

- Upper limit for the recursion depth. Is it *<= 2 * ceil(log2(n))* ?
- Upper limit for the number of comparisons. Is it *<= 2 * ceil(log2(n)) * n* ?
- Upper limit for the number of swaps. Is it *<= 2 * ceil(log2(n)) * n* ?

Ideally the algorithm is a famous one described in a famous paper, and the paper contains these upper limits as proofs. However, the libstdc++ source code doesn't specify any source.

For the *is it <= ...* questions above, I've got these formula conjectures by intuition, running the C program instrumented with counting for many inputs, and checking the upper limit for those inputs. However, I wasn't able to prove any of my conjectures in the general case. For the recursion depth formula, changing the constant from 2 to 1.5 makes it false, I've found some counterexamples.

Please note that I'm not interested in O(...) classes, but I want an actual upper limit, with a specific constant (hopefully 2 or less). I also need proofs for the upper limit formulas. A citation is enough as the proofs.

Based on comments and documentation of the implementations I think that both the number of comparisons and the number of swaps is *O(log2(n) * n)*. However, there is no proof, this is not an upper limit formula, and the formula for the recursion depth is missing.

It's quite easy to prove that in a regular (non-inplace) merge algorithm, there is no recursion, the number of comparisons is *<= n  - 1*, there are no swaps, and the number of copies is *n*. However, I'm specifically interested the inplace merge algorithm.

Above *n* is the total number of elements in the input/output array (== n1 + n2 == len1 + len2 == __len1 + __len2).

When calculating the number of swaps used by the rotate function, use 1 less than the total number of elements passed to the rotate function as an upper bound.

Here are some implementations of this algorithm:

- C++: [__merge_without_buffer](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/d76d19c9bc5ef1138af65fa3546eb628b7a756c9/libstdc%2B%2B-v3/include/bits/stl_algo.h#L2429-L2473) function in libstdc++, called by *std::inplace_merge*.
- Java: [merge](http://thomas.baudel.name/Visualisation/VisuTri/inplacestablesort.html), reimplementation of the C++ *__merge_without_buffer* function in Java.
- C: [ip_merge_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22839426/97248), simple reimplementation of the C++ *__merge_without_buffer* function in C.
- C: [ip_mergesort](https://github.com/pts/minilibc686/blob/17ecf444a2190dbe3cc5c9fd56402ace3ea5c7aa/test/test_qsort_stable_analyze.c#L10-L77): simple reimplementation of the C++ *__merge_without_buffer* function in C, based on *ip_merge_* above, and an in-place mergesort implementation with an interface compatible with [qsort(3)](https://linux.die.net/man/3/qsort).

Please note that the implementations above are equivalent for recursion depth, number of comparisons and number of swaps (as defined above).

This [blog post](https://xinok.wordpress.com/2014/08/17/in-place-merge-sort-demystified-2/) explains a different inplace mergesort. That algorithm swaps adjacent memory regions of the *same size* only.

The article [Practical In-Place Merging](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.88.1155&rep=rep1&type=pdf) (also explained in a [C++ code comment](https://keithschwarz.com/interesting/code/?dir=inplace-merge) here) explains a different inplace merge algorithm.

For completeness, I copy the C implementation here:

```c
#define SWAP(type, a, b) \
    do { type t=(a);(a)=(b);(b)=t; } while (0)

static void reverse_(int* a, int* b)
{
    for ( --b; a < b; a++, b-- )
       SWAP(int, *a, *b);
}
static int* rotate_(int* a, int* b, int* c)
/* swap the sequence [a,b) with [b,c). */
{
    if (a != b && b != c)
     {
       reverse_(a, b);
       reverse_(b, c);
       reverse_(a, c);
     }
    return a + (c - b);
}

static int* lower_bound_(int* a, int* b, const int key)
/* find first element not less than @p key in sorted sequence or end of
 * sequence (@p b) if not found. */
{
    int i;
    for ( i = b-a; i != 0; i /= 2 )
     {
       int* mid = a + i/2;
       if (*mid < key)
          a = mid + 1, i--;
     }
    return a;
}
static int* upper_bound_(int* a, int* b, const int key)
/* find first element greater than @p key in sorted sequence or end of
 * sequence (@p b) if not found. */
{
    int i;
    for ( i = b-a; i != 0; i /= 2 )
     {
       int* mid = a + i/2;
       if (*mid <= key)
          a = mid + 1, i--;
     }
    return a;
}

static void ip_merge_(int* a, int* b, int* c)
/* inplace merge. */
{
    int n1 = b - a;
    int n2 = c - b;

    if (n1 == 0 || n2 == 0)
       return;
    if (n1 == 1 && n2 == 1)
     {
       if (*b < *a)
          SWAP(int, *a, *b);
     }
    else
     {
       int* p, * q;

       if (n1 <= n2)
          p = upper_bound_(a, b, *(q = b+n2/2));
       else
          q = lower_bound_(b, c, *(p = a+n1/2));
       b = rotate_(p, b, q);

       ip_merge_(a, p, b);
       ip_merge_(b, q, c);
     }
}
```

Comment: Why is this tagged Java? And what specific question do you have about the time and space complexity? This looks like a homework dump.

Comment: @tgdavies: This is not a homework dump. Our algorithm analysis homeworks at university were much easier. My very specific questions are listed in the 3 bullet points near the beginning of the question (all 3 are formulas for the upper limit). I was trying to be very specific and clear about them. Do you have any advice how I could make them any clearer?

Comment: You're asking "Is it Is it <= 2 * ceil(log2(n))". Could you say: "I believe it is <= 2 * ceil(log2(n)), but I'm not certain because of [specific doubt you have about your proof]"? I think that would be an improvement.

Comment: @tgdavies: For these formulas all I have is some counting output for specific test inputs. I don't have a proof for the general case. I've added some more details to the question.

Comment: @tgdavies: I've added an answer containing my analysis so far. The problem with it is that the upper limit for the number of comparisons is *O(n**2)*, and I need *O(n * log(n))*, just like in [C++ std::inplace_merge](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inplace_merge). The algorithm is fast enough, but the analysis is not precise enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Upper limit for the recursion depth.

It's relatively easy to prove that that total item size (*b-a* and *c-b*) of each recursive call is between *floor((c-a)/4)* and *ceil((c-a)*3/4)*, and their sum is *c-a*.

From this it's easy to prove that the recursion depth is *O(log(c-a))*. More specifically, it's less than *log(c-a)/log(4/3)+1*.

> Upper limit for the number of swaps.

It's easy to prove that the total number of swaps needed by `rotate_(p, b, q)` is at most *q-p*. It's also easy to prove that *q-p <= ceil((c-a)*3/4)*.

To get the total number of swaps, we have to count all the `rotate_` calls in the main call and in the recursive call. It's reletively easy to prove that the total will be *O(n*log(n))*, and after that it's possible to prove that it's at most *3*n*log2(n)*.

> Upper limit for the number of comparisons.

It's easy to prove that the number of comparisons in the `upper_bound_` and `lower_bound_` calls is at most *ceil(log2(floor((c-a)/2)+1))*. That's less than the number of swaps in the `rotate_` call. Thus the number of comparisons is less than the number of swaps. Actually it's much less, only a tiny bit more than *O(n)*, but wasn't able to prove it.

> Number of swaps in a mergesort.

I used the following algorithm to implement an in-place mergesort of *n* items:

```c
void ip_mergesort_(int *base, int n) {
  int a, b, d;
  for (d = 1; d < n; d <<= 1) {
    for (a = 0; a < n - d; a = b) {
      b = a + (d << 1);
      ip_merge_(base + a, base + (a + d), base + (b > n ? n : b));
    }
  }
}
```

I was able to prove that the number of swaps in this mergesort is *O(n*log(n)*log(n))*. I was able to measure (but not prove) these bounds:

- If *n <= 1*, then *0*.
- If *n == 2*, then at most *1*.
- If *n >= 2*, then less than *0.75 * n * log2(n) * log2(n)*.

> Number of comparisons in a mergesort.

I was able to prove that the number of comparisons in the mergesort above is *O(n*log(n)*log(n))*. I was able to measure (but not prove) these bounds:

- If *n <= 1*, then *0*.
- If *n == 2*, then at most *1*.
- If *n >= 2*, then less than *0.5 * n * log2(n) * log2(n)*.
- If *2 <= n <= 2**32*, then less than *1.9683 * n * log2(n)*.
- If *2 <= n <= 2**64*, then less than *1.9998 * n * log2(n)*.
- If *2 <= n <= 2**128*, then less than *2.0154 * n * log2(n)*.
- If *2 <= n <= 2**256*, then less than *2.0232 * n * log2(n)*.
- If *2 <= n <= 2**512*, then less than *2.0270 * n * log2(n)*.

---

More details of the analysis and measurements here: [C code with comments](https://github.com/pts/minilibc686/blob/e1f1daa3b93c9f3c06d420f70f4e2b1873aad1fe/test/test_qsort_stable_analyze.c), [Python script doing the measurements](https://github.com/pts/minilibc686/blob/e1f1daa3b93c9f3c06d420f70f4e2b1873aad1fe/fyi/qsort_stable_analyze.py).