# In-Place Sorting of Two sorted Arrays, in a way to store the first n items in the first array and the rest in the other

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

explanation of the question:
In this question, you are given two arrays of integers with lengths n and m. These arrays are sorted in ascending order. We want you to store the n smallest elements from the given numbers in the first array and the remaining numbers in the second array. (Note that the algorithm you implement should be in-place.)
The first line of the input provides the numbers n and m in order. In the next two lines, the elements of the first array are given first, followed by the elements of the second array.
0<=n,m<=1000
The output of your program should display the requested elements from the first array initially in the first line, followed by the elements of the second array in the next line. Note that your output should be sorted.
Example:

```
Input:
5 3
1 4 7 8 10
2 3 9

Output:
1 2 3 4 7
8 9 10
```

Note that the time complicity of the code that you provide must not be more than O(m.n).
I insist that it must be an in-place solution.
My solution:
I have actually come up with the following solution and I have used merge sort. But the problem is that it is not in-place.
Any hint or link that can guide me to overcome this problem is appreciated.
Code:
'''

```
def merge_sort(array):

    if len(array) <= 1:
        return array

    mid = len(array) // 2
    left_half = array[:mid]
    right_half = array[mid:]

    left_half = merge_sort(left_half)
    right_half = merge_sort(right_half)

    return merge(left_half, right_half)

def merge(left, right):
    merged = []
    left_index = 0
    right_index = 0

    while left_index < len(left) and right_index < len(right):
        if left[left_index] <= right[right_index]:
            merged.append(left[left_index])
            left_index += 1
        else:
            merged.append(right[right_index])
            right_index += 1

    while left_index < len(left):
        merged.append(left[left_index])
        left_index += 1

    while right_index < len(right):
        merged.append(right[right_index])
        right_index += 1

    return merged

def store_nsmallest_elements(array1, array2, n, m):
    sorted_array = merge_sort(array1 + array2)
    return sorted_array[:n], sorted_array[n:n+m]

n, m = map(int, input().split())
array1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
array2 = list(map(int, input().split()))

first, second = store_nsmallest_elements(array1, array2, n, m)

print(*first)
print(*second)
```

'''

Comment: Which kind of "in-place" do you mean?

Comment: What do you mean by O(m.n)?

Comment: @KennyOstrom If your simple linear time merge with swaps that you had mentioned actually works, please post it as an *answer* (and with more explanation, because based on what you had said, I don't think it works).

Comment: It is important to note that the OP's code works the same just calling merge instead of merge_sort -- you already have the two lists to merge as inputs.

Comment: OP this link has some useful info on a closely related question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm/15657134#15657134

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution is to define custom functions for `len`/`get`/`set` which work on two arrays and then implement custom in-place sort (e.g. bubble-sort, insertion sort etc.). Here is an example with insertion sort:

```py
# return a length of arr1 + arr2
def custom_len(arr1, arr2):
    return len(arr1) + len(arr2)


# return a value from arr1/arr2 at index i (treat the two arrays as one big array)
def custom_get(arr1, arr2, i):
    if i < len(arr1):
        return arr1[i]
    return arr2[i - len(arr1)]

# set value val in arr1/arr2 at index i (treat the two arrays as one big array)
def custom_set(arr1, arr2, i, val):
    if i < len(arr1):
        arr1[i] = val
    else:
        arr2[i - len(arr1)] = val


def insertion_sort(arr1, arr2):
    n = custom_len(arr1, arr2)

    for i in range(1, n):
        key = custom_get(arr1, arr2, i)
        j = i - 1

        while j >= 0 and key < custom_get(arr1, arr2, j):
            custom_set(arr1, arr2, j + 1, custom_get(arr1, arr2, j))
            j -= 1

        custom_set(arr1, arr2, j + 1, key)


array1 = [1, 4, 7, 8, 10]
array2 = [2, 3, 9]

insertion_sort(array1, array2)

print(array1)
print(array2)
```

Prints:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
[8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: How about an OOP version with `insertion_sort(Chain(array1, array2))`? (,Where the Chain object acts like a single list and the sort function is ordinary insertion sort, not knowing about the two lists)

Comment: @KellyBundy Yes, that could be nice too :) (actually, that how I'd implement it in real code). But I assume, this is just another *leetcode* problem, so nothing for real use-case.

Comment: Bubble sort doesn't achieve the required O(m.n), does it?

Comment: @KellyBundy Yeah, bubble-sort is worst case (m + n)^2, but the arrays are already sorted, so the performance should be better.

Comment: Maybe I'm just to tired, but I find it surprisingly difficult to think through. Unlike with insertion sort.

Comment: I like the idea of simply transforming the "sort two lists" problem into a "sort one list" problem (upvoted). But ignoring the info of where the two presorted sublists are really hurts our ability to deliver on performance.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
    array1[:] = sorted_array[:n]
    array2[:] = sorted_array[n:n+m]
```

in `store_nsmallest_elements`. This will **replace** the values inside `array1` and `array2`.

Then the function would look like so:

```
def store_nsmallest_elements(array1, array2, n, m):
    sorted_array = merge_sort(array1 + array2)
    array1[:] = sorted_array[:n]
    array2[:] = sorted_array[n:n+m]
    return sorted_array[:n], sorted_array[n:n+m]
```

- You don't need to use `return`.  I only used it because it was in the original code.

---

#### Output:

```
5 3
1 4 7 8 10
2 3 9
----
Before:
----
array1: [1, 4, 7, 8, 10]
array2: [2, 3, 9]
----
After:
----
first returned: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
first original: [1, 2, 3, 4, 7]
second returned: [8, 9, 10]
second original: [8, 9, 10]
```

#### Code:

(I only changed the printing)

```
n, m = map(int, input().split())
array1 = list(map(int, input().split()))
array2 = list(map(int, input().split()))

print("----\nBefore:\n----")
print(f'array1: {array1}\narray2: {array2}')

first, second = store_nsmallest_elements(array1, array2, n, m)

print("----\nAfter:\n----")
print(f'first returned: {first}\nfirst original: {array1}\nsecond returned: {second}\nsecond original: {array2}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Another insertion short solution like Andrej's, but more OOP-ish and with a standard insertion sort that doesn't even know about there being two arrays:

```py
def chain(a, b):
    n, m = len(a), len(b)
    class Chain:
        def __len__(self):
            return n + m
        def __getitem__(self, i):
           return a[i] if i < n else b[i-n]
        def __setitem__(self, i, val):
            if i < n:
                a[i] = val
            else:
                b[i-n] = val
    return Chain()

def insertion_sort(A):
    for i, a in enumerate(A):
        while i and a < A[i-1]:
            A[i] = A[i-1]
            i -= 1
        A[i] = a

array1 = [1, 4, 7, 8, 10]
array2 = [2, 3, 9]

insertion_sort(chain(array1, array2))

print(array1)
print(array2)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZVJLTsMwEJVY-hRvGQtXIgGJgtpFxTGiKHLbCbGUOJXtgnoWNt3AoTgNduxCE2YTZ95nnq35-DqcXDvo8_nz6JrF8vum2lODXSuVzqTAlj8z-NICPdboyHe5GL9bPiK7TlqLlyCI1FDBo649q64zS13D_6BQhtzRaGjcop9pXskpR33SCaipNCllqSqoBgor70KdJWxLtdDVzM3O3QTeZDdLc_GZdkONY9ZBMoHCvP_kGOCKnrKOT5NxxkIkpS0ZpwZd28G4bJOiNIMJ2aTHQfrYk5GOftFQ763qyOeUeu9pK2z8tLyaptjEuBGaXhGLNXI2I0rGpDHylPtzmQs8CDwKLAXyuyoiRUAKgXuBp4qxWfq0JaOFDz8KuL_owSjtUp9f_xU8bllatsvS_QA)