# in-place permutation of a array follows this rule

Tags: algorithm

Suppose there is an array, we want to find everything in the odd index (index starting with 0), and move it to the end.
Everything in the even index move it to the beginning.
The relative order of all odd index items and all even index items are preserved.

i.e. if the array is

```
a1 b1 a2 b2 ...  an bn
```

after the operation it becomes

```
a1 a2 a3 ... an b1 b2 ... bn
```

Can this be done in-place and in O(n) time?

Comment: Smells like homework?

Comment: By "in-place" do you mean "using O(1) memory", or is it allowed to use additional memory for computing the intermediate transformation? I suspect the former is *not* possible.

Comment: Other than the memory storing the array, I'm allowed to use O(1) memory. Not homework. I'm trying to save 50% of the memory usage a program that have to work on a really really large array.

Comment: Did you consider not doing it at all? What I mean is that since there is a function that can map the old indexes to new and new to old you could access the old in a new order without moving anything.

Comment: @Mgccl: It is possible in O(n) time and O(1) space, but it is very complicated. See my answer. I suggest you use the O(nlogn) time one, as that is easier on the cache.

Comment: @Chris: No way is this homework!

Comment: @Unreason: Very insightful! I can't think of any practical reason to use this kind of shuffle anymore. Originally, I'm calling this in some recursion, and it runs only on the 0 to n/2^k th of the array at kth recursion. That's the reason I wanted the shuffle, put all the even index from 0 to n/2^(k-1) in the beginning so the next recursion only work on the even index from the last recursion. Now I just have to come up with the 1-to-1 mapping for this problem.

Comment: @Mgccl: If the sub-array you need to permute keeps changing, it might become difficult to use the 'index adaptor' solution. Did you manage to come up with a mapping? Looks like you will have to chain together the 'index adaptors' and remember which adaptor applies to which sub-array.

Comment: @Moron http://www.bearcave.com/software/java/wavelets/doc/index.html this thing does what I want(using iterations). on recursion level j, the index for the kth item in the odd index is 2^j*2k+1, in the even index is 2^j*2k. so it never process something that had a odd index. Quite elegant.

Comment: @Mgccl: Great that you found a better solution for your specific case. May I ask what you are doing this for?

Comment: @Moron: I was implementing a lifting scheme. It start with a split(split the array into odd and even index ones),do stuff to odd and even part separately, and then run lifting scheme on the even parts. So I thought about placing all the even ones in the front, then the recursion will only do stuff to the beginning part of array. Wikipedia said the lifting scheme can be done in place, so I thought there should be a way to do the thing stated in the original question.

Comment: @Mgccl: I see. I am guessing the wiki is talking about the bit-reversal property which you get after you do this shuffling recursively many times. See this: http://www.dspguide.com/ch12/2.htm. The way you asked it, it was only for one shuffle and that is possible too :-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible, but it is very complicated! A simpler O(nlogn) and O(1) space solution might be better to code and in terms of cache.

We will solve a problem different from yours, but your problem is trivial to solve once we solve that problem.

Consider the array to be

```
b1, a1, b2, a2, ..., bn, an
```

and you have to convert this to

```
a1, a2, ..., an, b1, b2, ..., bn
```

Working with indices 1 to 2n,

we see that this is given by

```
i -> (n+1)*i (mod 2n+1).
```

---

**An O(nlogn) time O(1) space solution**

We can use divide and conquer as follows.

First for some m close to n/2 convert

`b1, a1, ..., bn , an`

to

```
a1,a2,...am, b1,b2, ..bm, a(m+1), ..., an, b(m+1), ... , bn
```

by recursively applying to first 2m elements, and then the remaining.

Now all we need to do this cyclic shift the middle array by m spots (this can be done in O(n) time and O(1) space)

to give

```
a1, a2, .., am , a(m+1), ..., an, b1, b2, ..., bm, b(m+1), ..., bn.
```

Of course, as IVlad pointed out, this needs O(logn) stack space. We can get around that by doing the following:

We have:

```
b1 a1, b2 a2, .. bm am, b(m+1) a(m+1), ..., bn an
```

Now swap pairs in the latter part of the array to give

```
b1 a1, b2 a2, .. bm am, a(m+1) b(m+1), ..., an bn
```

Now cyclic shift the elements at odd position: `b1, b2, .., bm, a(m+1), a(m+2) ..., a(n).`

This gives something like

```
a(m+1) a1, a(m+2) a2, ..., a(2m) am, a(2m+1) b(m+1),...,an b(n-m), b1 b(n-m+1),...,bm bn
```

Now again swap the latter part of the array to give

```
a(m+1) a1, a(m+2) a2, ..., a(2m) am, b(m+1) a(2m+1),...,b(n-m) an,b(n-m+1) b1,..., bn bm
```

Now recursively solve the first part and second part to give

```
[a1 a2 ... am][a(m+1) ... a(2m)]   [a(2m+1) ...an b1 b2 .. bm][b(m+1) ... bn]
```

This works whether 2m >= n or not.

So, this is O(nlogn) time and O(1) space algorithm.

---

**An O(n) time O(1) space solution.**

The ideas used are similar to the ideas used in the following paper:
[A simple in-place algorithm for Inshuffle](http://arxiv.org/abs/0805.1598).

You would need to read that paper to understand the below. I suggest you also read: [How to master in-place array modification algorithms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2352542/how-to-master-in-place-array-modification-algorithms)

This is basically the inverse permutation of what is solved in the paper above.

It is enough to solve this when 2n+1 is a power of 3  = (3^m say), as we can use divide and conquer after that (like the O(nlogn) solution).

Now 2n+1 and n+1 are relatively prime, so working modulo 3^m, we see that n+1 *must* be some power of 2. (See that paper again to see why: basically any number modulo 3^m which is relative prime to 3^m is a power of 2, again modulo 3^m).

Say n+1 = 2^k (we don't know k yet and note this is modulo 3^m).

A way to find out k, compute powers of n+1 modulo 3^m, till it becomes 1. This gives us k (and is O(n) time at most).

Now we can see that the cycles of the permutation (see above paper/stackoverflow link for what that is) start at

2^a*3^b

where 0 <= a < k, and 0 <= b < m.

So you start with each possible pair (a,b) and follow the cycles of the permutation, and this gives an O(n) time, in-place algorithm, as you touch each element no more than a constant number of times!

This was a bit brief(!) and if you need more info, please let me know.

Comment: Doesn't the recursion make (at least) the first solution `O(log n)` in memory usage?

Comment: @IVlad: Good point! Usually stack space is already there (i.e. we don't really have to allocate it) and so O(logn) recursive calls of small functions (i.e. very few local variables) are still considered O(1) space, if they don't manage to overflow the stack. You are correct, though. Perhaps there is a way to do this with tail recursion... have to think about it.

Comment: This is great! Thanks a lot :D
To someone who is reading the chosen solution:
Also read unreason's comment to the problem. It made me realize that the explicit shuffle is not required for most(if not every) practical reason one want to do this.

Comment: @Mgccl: Explicit shuffle might be required, for instance in embedded devices, where memory is low and you need in-place algorithms. I would say, it is more likely that if you need in-place, then you might need the explicit shuffle! Anyway, this is all talk without supporting data :-)

Comment: @IVlad: I have edited the answer to remove the reliance on the recursive calls by making it tail recursive.

Answer (score 3):

What you have is an N X 2 matrix represented in a one dimentional array that you want transposed into a 2 X N array.

For example your list:

a<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, ... a<sub>n</sub>, b<sub>n</sub>

can just as well be represented as the matrix:

x<sub>1,1</sub>, x<sub>1,2</sub>, x<sub>2,1</sub>, x<sub>2,2</sub>, ... x<sub>n,1</sub>, x<sub>n,2</sub>

Which you want to transpose to become:

x<sub>1,1</sub>, x<sub>2,1</sub>, ... x<sub>n,1</sub>, x<sub>1,2</sub>, x<sub>2,2</sub>, ... x<sub>n,2</sub>

The [in place matrix transposition algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In-place_matrix_transposition) will do the job.

**EDIT**

Ok let me spell it out. Try the following bit of code:

```
i = 0                /* linear array index */
do j = 1 to c        /* j = 1 to virtural columns */
  do k = 1 to r      /* k = 1 to virtural rows */
    i = i + 1
    sp = (k - 1) * c + j
    do while sp < i
      ct = (sp - 1) % r + 1
      rt = sp - (ct - 1) * r
      sp = (rt - 1) * c + ct
    end
    if i \= sp then say 'swap('i',' sp')'   /* swap elements */
  end
end
```

This will print out the array elements that need to be swapped. This will work for any sized matrix represented in a linear array where the elements are arranged by column then row. Using an N X 2 martix, the elements would be arranged as follows:

x<sub>1,1</sub>, x<sub>1,2</sub>, x<sub>2,1</sub>, x<sub>2,2</sub>, ... x<sub>n,1</sub>, x<sub>n,2</sub>

The algorithm prints out the elements that need to be swapped to yield an array orderd as follows:

x<sub>1,1</sub>, x<sub>2,1</sub>, ... x<sub>n,1</sub>, x<sub>1,2</sub>, x<sub>2,2</sub>, ... x<sub>n,2</sub>

For example, start with r = 4, c = 2 and the array:

```
 A1, B1, A2, B2, A3, B3, A4, B4
```

Requires the following swaps:

```
swap(2, 3)
swap(3, 5)
swap(4, 7)
swap(6, 7)
```

to become:

```
 A1, A2, A3, A4, B1, B2, B3, B4
```

This algorithm is efficient in both space and time.

**Big-O**

My O-foo is not great but I will give it a shot...

The matrix contains 2 columns ('A' and 'B') and 'M' rows. To represent this as
a linear array we need 2M elements. Lets call that number N (the size of the linear array).

The algorithm has two iteration loops, one for 'r' (rows) and one for 'c' (columns). 
Total iterations is then r * c which in our case comes down to 2M = N. So far so good.

The wild card is the inner `DO WHILE` loop. How many iterations does it require for a given number of rows? 
The answer may be: Quite a few. 
Based on some empirical results (shown below) it looks like the number of `DO WHILE` iterations 
is a complex function involving 'r' when 'c' = 2 (or probably any value of 'c'). 
I do not have enough O-foo to figure out exactly what this function is.
However, it should not get any worse than N<sup>3</sup> (one complete 'chase' through the matrix, N<sup>2</sup>, times
every element, N). Not a good picture - in theory. So I guess that makes it O(N<sup>3</sup>)? This may be
a non O(N) algorithm, but in practical terms appears to perform close to O(N) given the bits of
empirical data below. I'm kind of lost at this point - comments welcome!

One observation about the `DO WHILE` loop though: It is using integer based math on simple variables (no array
references required). If you are going non-linear this has got
to be the 'cheapest' place to do it!

How many swaps are required? The number of swaps is limited to one per iteration through the outer
two loops, which is at most N times. The number of swaps is in line with an O(N) performance.

My guess is that this is a non O(N) algorithm, but does appear to have reasonable behavior 
for 2 column matrices of moderate size.

Here are some empirical results for various 2 column matrix sizes:

```
      Rows Loops per row
========== =============
       500             9
     1,000            19
     1,500            21
     2,000            12
     2,500            18
     3,000            23
     3,500            26
 1,000,000            30
 2,000,000            40
 3,000,000            45
10,000,000            59
20,000,000            39
30,000,000            60
```

The 'loops per row' grow with row count, but not at an alarming rate. The danger is of hitting some 'sweet' spot where it goes exponential - but I don't know if it really has that potential.

My advice to Mgccl would be to benchmark this algorithm over the range of row counts that are
typical in his application then decide if it would yield an acceptable performance relative to other
algorithm benchmarks. Big-O analysis
is interesting, but results over an operational range of data are what count.

**Last kick at the can:** Why does this algorithm work?

Transpose a matrix represented in linear form:

Given matrix X having M rows and N columns.

Lay X out into a linear array in row major order. The
array will be organized as follows:

```
11, 12, 13, ... 1N, 21, 22, 23, ... 2N, ... M1, M2, M3 ... MN
```

A notation describing each element in the linear array
is:

```
    X[i,r,c] 

where: i is the linear array index for element X 
       r is the row number for element X
       c is the column number for element X.
```

Using this notation,
an array in row major order can be generated as:

```
i = 0
for j = 1 to M    /* Row counter */
  for k = 1 to N  /* Column counter */
    i = i + 1     /* array index of element j, k */
    say 'X['i','j',k']'
  end
end
```

Note that given values for j (row) and k (column), i may be calculated as:

```
i = (j - 1) * N + k
```

The transpose of matrix X is constructed by exchanging the elements
X[i,r,c] with X[t,c,r] over the range of r and c. In essence we exchange
all row variables for column variables. Using the notation
described above, this amounts to exchanging linear array elements:

```
    exchange(X[i,r,c], X[t,c,r])

where: i = (r - 1) * N + c
       t = (c - 1) * M + i
```

The number of exchanges required to transpose the matrix will be less than
M * N because at most one exchange is ever required to place an element into its correct
position. In some cases an exchange will not be required because the
element is already 'in place'. For example the first and last elements of X
never need exchanging.

By proceeding through the linear array by increasing i, we know that as long as
none of the exchanges involve elements where i > t, the matrix will be in
column major order for all elements having indexes less than or equal to i.

Whenever i > t, it means that a prior exchange took place at index t.
The element at t was exchanged as indicated above placing it
at some new position t'. Given an index t, we may calculate the row major index t'
as well as the row and column numbers associate with it as follows:

```
 c' = (t - 1) % M + 1
 r' = t - (c' - 1) * M
 t' = (r' - 1) * N + c'
```

Again, if t' is less than i, it means that this element was exchanged too and we must
continue with another round of calculations. Set t to the calculated t' and repeat.
Eventually, i will become <= t and
the exchange may be done. Basically we 'chase' the element through all of its
prior exchanges until we find it at i or to the right of i in the linear
array.

Repeat this cycle for each element in the linear array and the matrix will have
been transposed.

Comment: Doesn't the algorithm need an array of size 2N instead? The index has to be stored explicitly in order for this to work. the reason it can be stored in 1d array of size N in first place is because the array have a implicit order.

Comment: This is overkill and the some of the 'simpler' algorithms there use O(M+N) space (which is O(N) for us!).

Comment: @Mgccl @Moron I think you misunderstood my post. I have edited it to give both a specific algorithm and example. No recursion, no extra memory, linear time relative to the length of the array. Have a look.

Comment: @Nealb: Are you sure it is O(n)? I suggest you try and prove it.

Comment: @Moron - I took a shot at big-O, probably missed. Comments welcome.

Comment: @Nealb: So, it does not look like O(n). Also, I am concerned about the correctness of this algorithm. What exactly are you doing to determine the swaps? It is not very clear from the code. One reason for the concern: you claim it works for MxN array in O(MN) time and O(1) space. If it was that simple, the wiki page would have a reference. There are only references to complicated algorithms and O(MN) time and O(1) space seems to be unsolved in general (I might be wrong about that though).

Comment: @Nealb: So for each cycle of length k, you iterate k times for each element in the cycle, so total k^2, right? This looks to be a quadratic algorithm.

Comment: @moron, The innermost DO loop cannot take more than N * M iterations in the worst case (calculating the index of every row/column in the matrix). It needs to do this N * M times (outer pair of DO loops traversing the entire array from left to right). This gives an absolute worst case of (N*M)^2. However, I suspect that actual performance for any choosen values for M and N is actually quite a bit better (based on benchmarks) - I don't know how to prove it though. So yes, I would have to say it is quadratic as a worst case.

Comment: @Nealb: I am guessing on an average this will be O((NM/logMN)^2). This is one problem where the number of swaps will oscillate as the size increases. So instead choosing isolated values like 1 million, 2 million, I suggest you do a range like 1,000,000 to 1,100,000 etc.

Comment: @Moron. I ran every 2 column matrix with rows ranging from 100 to 10,000. The best performing row choice (128) averaged 4 iterations through the inner loop per row. The worst case (9,487) required an average of 37 iterations per row. This suggests O((MN/logMN)^2) is an over estimate for worst case performance. I noticed that as the row counts grow so do the average number of iterations per row. This observation suggests to me that the algorithm is exponential in some way (but still reasonably well behaved for small to moderately large matrices).

Comment: @Nealb. It was just a guess. In any case, you can't really tell from just a few values. O(blah) hides a hidden constant, which could be very small/big etc.

Comment: could you pleas clarify the index range of j and k ? Are c and r included in their respective ranges? The notation suggests this, but it seems unintuitive, in particular if you are used to write for-loops in any C- or Java-like way.

Comment: @Martin Took me a couple of minutes to figure out what was confusing you. I used r and c a little differently in different parts of my answer (joys of multiple edit sessions). Before "last kick at the can" r was total number of rows in the matrix, k was an index ranging from 1 to r. c was the total number of columns. After that I started using N to represent number of columns and c just became an index (ranging from 1 to N). r became M (number of rows). Don't have time now but I will try to re-edit the answer a little later. Also, array indices are 1 based (not zero as in C/java)

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's look at this example:

0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

0 2 4 6 8 10 1 3 5 7 9

First half of the result contains elements with their indices being i / 2 of the original index i, while the other half is i - n / 2 + 1, where n is the number of items in the array.

This is basically a special case of sorting algorithms, only with a special order being set.

So here is an idea to use a bubblesort algorithm to sort an array of integers. What we need is to pull the even values to the beginning leaving odd values behind:

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
  * *
0 2 1 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
      * *
0 2 1 4 3 5 6 7 8 9 10
    * *
0 2 4 1 3 5 6 7 8 9 10
          * *
0 2 4 1 3 6 5 7 8 9 10
        * *
...
0 2 4 6 1 3 5 7 8 9 10
              * *
...
0 2 4 6 8 1 3 5 7 9 10
                  * *
```

This will only work if you can preserve the indices (i.e. in this case indices correlate with array values), though. And bubblesort's performance is O(n^2) and memory usage is 1.

It cannot be accomplished in O(n) time and 1 memory [EDIT: using just generic sorting algoritms!], best generic sorting algorithms perform in O(nlog n):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm

To solve your problem, the best way would be to generate an array of indices matching your criterium:

```
size_t* indices = new size_t[n]; 

// n is the number of items in the original array
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    if (i < n / 2)
    {
       indices[i] = i * 2;
    }
    else
    {
       indices[i] = i - n / 2 + 1;
    }
}
```

and then simply use it to map the items in the original array to new positions:

```
// i is the new index here, which makes it appear as if ValuesArray has been sorted
Type* getOddEvenValue(size_t newIndex)
{
     // ValuesArray and indices should be available in this scope, of course
     return ValuesArray[indices[newIndex]];
}
```

This thing would run in O(n) but would also require O(n) memory. But if the sizeof Type is much bigger than sizeof int, then it's still a gain in memory usage (as opposed to copying Type objects).

[EDIT2:]

Instead of the nice OOP code andand did, which also requires you to copy the original vector into your class' instance, you could simply write a function:

```
 size_t permuted_index(size_t i, size_t vecSize)
 {
    return ( i < vecSize/2 ? i * 2 : 2 * (i - vecSize/2) + 1);
 }
```

and use that whenever you need to get the permutted value. Indeed, this only requires O(n) time, since permutted_index would then be evaluated no more than n times for the given vector (in a full "for each" loop, at least).

Comment: O(n) time and O(1) space _is_ possible.

Comment: Well, yes, andand actually demonstrated it. His solution could be implemented procedurally, too, BTW -- classes were simply for OOP goodness. 

Unfortunately, I didn't quite grasp your solution. Seems to be more complex, than needed.

Comment: As stated, andand's solution does not solve the problem. It just adds a layer of indirection when retreiving the element. There is actually no physical shifting going on. For instance, say you had to repeat this multiple times for different length sub-arrays etc. That solution won't work any more...

Comment: @Moron: It did solve the initial problem with integer indices. The genericized problem cannot be solved by this approach, indeed.

Answer (score 0):

**O(1) Time, O(1) Additional Space**

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <boost/random.hpp>

template <typename T>
class pvec
{
private:
    // Stores values to permute
    std::vector<T> v;

    // Flag; true when permuted; false when not
    bool permuted;

public:
    pvec(size_t size) : v(size), permuted(false) {}

    // Set the permutation flag
    void set_p(bool p) { permuted = p; }

    // When the permuted flag is set, return the permuted element, otherwise
    // return the non-permuted element
    T& operator[](size_t i) { return (permuted ? v[p_ind(i)] : v[i]); }

    // Pass through the size of the vector used
    size_t size() const { return v.size(); }

private:
    // Used to determine the permuted index of a given index
    size_t p_ind(size_t i) const
    {
        return ( i < v.size()/2 ? i * 2 : 2 * (i - v.size()/2) + 1);
    }
};

// Used to display a pvec instance
template <typename T>
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, pvec<T>& v)
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < v.size(); ++i)
        os << (i == 0 ? "<" : ", ") << i << ":" << v[i];
    os << ">";
    return os;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    const size_t size = 8;
    pvec<uint32_t> v(size);  // Array containing test values

    // Boost Random Number Library used to generate random values in the test
    // array
    boost::mt19937 rng(std::time(0));
    boost::uniform_int<> dist(0,65536);
    boost::variate_generator<boost::mt19937&, boost::uniform_int<> >
        var(rng, dist);

    // Generate random test values
    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        v[i] = var();

    // Observer original vector
    std::cout << v << std::endl;

    // Set the permutation flag O(1) time
    v.set_p(true);

    // Observe the permuted vector
    std::cout << v << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
<0:44961, 1:246, 2:54618, 3:41468, 4:12646, 5:21691, 6:26697, 7:36409>
<0:44961, 1:54618, 2:12646, 3:26697, 4:246, 5:41468, 6:21691, 7:36409>
```

Comment: This isn't `O(1)` because printing the answer is itself `O(n)`. Also, the question clearly asks to **move** the elements in a certain way, not to just print them. Also, C++ mixed with boost and complicated classes is a bad idea for an answer to an algorithmic question. Pseudocode or easier to understand C++ would've been much more helpful. -1.

Comment: @IVlad: The permutation involves setting a flag to tell the class to invoke the permutation, which is O(1); true, the observation is O(N) but that was just for illustration purposes. As for the issue of the move, the class abstracts the necessity of that away; it achieves the effect of moving the elements in the specified permutation without actually doing it. As for Boost, it's just there to populate the sample array with random values ... the meat is in the class.

Comment: @IVlad: Also you might want to read the OP's subsequent comments about not requiring explicit moves.

Comment: I still think pseudocode would've been much better for this question, but seeing that you added comments, I removed the vote.

Comment: @IVlad: I'll grant you that; but from my perspective, I wanted to make sure that it worked and that I could verify that the math behind the permutation worked properly.

Comment: Any attempt of getting a sequence of items in memory (either for printing or otherwise) will give you O(n) run time. But O(n) time / O(i) memory is good, too!